# Avoid clipping of points along axis in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, clipping

I am plotting a time series with mean values of a response variable as points (y-axis) by month (x-axis).

Values lying on the x-axis (i.e. 0 values) are clipped. I can change the limits of the y-axis to include some padding below 0, but I prefer not to.

Is there a way to plot these 0 points in front of, or on-top of the x-axis?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this,

```
q <- qplot(1:10,1:10,size=I(10)) + scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0))
gt <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(q))
gt$layout$clip[gt$layout$name=="panel"] <- "off"
grid.draw(gt)
```

[image: clipoff]

Comment: Will do, and try again.  Thank you!

Comment: Subbing in the following code turns off clipping when faceting: `gt$layout$clip[grep("panel",gt$layout$name)] <- "off"`

Comment: how would you turn `gt` back into a ggplot/gg object?

Comment: i doubt you can, it's like turning a baked cake into flour and eggs

Comment: Is there a way to only turn off clipping on the x-axis but keep it on the y-axis?

Comment: This solution doesn't work when the plot contains axes; try adding **color = "red" to the aesthetics** and + theme_bw() to the first line of the code. The axis appears on top of the red dots. (I haven't found a solution yet.)

Answer (score 16):

With the release of ggplot2 version 3.0.0, you can simply use `coord_cartesian(clip = 'off')`.

```
library(ggplot2)

qplot(x = 1:10, y = 1:10, size=I(10)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0)) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = 'off') +
  labs(title = "coord_cartesian(clip = 'off')")
```

[image]

If you're using one of the less commonly-used `coord_*` systems or functions (e.g. `coord_polar` or `coord_flip`), then you can use the `clip = 'off'` argument there, too.

```
my_plot + 
coord_flip(clip = 'off')
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! Your point is now incorporated into the answer.

Comment: This solution doesn't work when the plot contains axes; try adding **color = "red"** to the aesthetics and **+ theme_bw()** to the end of the code. The axis appears on top of the red dots. (I haven't found a solution yet.)

Comment: That's a good point. I'd recommend opening a new question to address that, because it's a separate issue and a good question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use attribute expand() on the scale_y
Exemple for 10% each side of y scale :

```
ggplot(mydata, aes(y = value, x = mydate)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0.1,0.1))
```

Comment: Thank you.  This works by expanding the range of the y axis.  It works nicely, but I would prefer something like that suggested by baptiste above.  i.e., the x axis starts at 0, but the 0 points are plotted on-top of it.  Thank you for your help, though.

Comment: I think that should be `+ scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0.1,0.1))`.

Answer (score -1):

If you were using base graphics you could use clip().

```
plot(1:4)
clip(-0.5, 4.1, -0.5, 4.1)
points(0.85, 1, col = 'red', cex = 2)
```

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to make this work within ggplot script.  I also tried plotting the figure, then clipping and adding a point on top.  But that did not work either.  Thanks.