# Displaying text below the plot generated by ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to display some information about the data below the plot created in **ggplot2**. I would like to plot the N variable using the X axis coordinate of the plot but the Y coordinate needs to be 10% from the bottom of the screen . In fact, the desired Y coordinates are already in the data frame as y_pos variable.

I can think of 3 approaches using **ggplot2**:

1) Create an empty plot below the actual plot, use the same scale and then use geom_text to plot the data over the blank plot. [This approach](http://learnr.wordpress.com/2009/04/29/ggplot2-labelling-data-series-and-adding-a-data-table/) sort of works but is extremely complicated.

2) Use `geom_text` to plot the data but somehow use y coordinate as percent of the screen (10%). This would force the numbers to be displayed below the plot. I can't figure out the proper syntax.

3) Use grid.text to display the text. I can easily set it at the 10% from the bottom of the screen but I can't figure how set the X coordindate to match the plot. I tried to use grconvert to capture the initial X position but could not get that to work as well.

Below is the basic plot with the dummy data:

```
graphics.off()      # close graphics windows   

library(car)
library(ggplot2)  #load ggplot
library(gridExtra) #load Grid
library(RGraphics) # support of the "R graphics" book, on CRAN

#create dummy data
test= data.frame(
  Group = c("A", "B", "A","B", "A", "B"), 
  x = c(1 ,1,2,2,3,3 ),
  y = c(33,25,27,36,43,25),
  n=c(71,55,65,58,65,58),
  y_pos=c(9,6,9,6,9,6)
  )

#create ggplot
p1 <- qplot(x, y, data=test, colour=Group) +
  ylab("Mean change from baseline") + 
  geom_line()+
  scale_x_continuous("Weeks", breaks=seq(-1,3, by = 1) ) +
  opts( 
        legend.position=c(.1,0.9))

#display plot
p1
```

The modified gplot  below displays numbers of subjects, however they are displayed WITHIN the plot. They force the Y scale to be extended. I would like to display these numbers BELOW the plot.

```
    p1 <- qplot(x, y, data=test, colour=Group) +
  ylab("Mean change from baseline") + 
  geom_line()+
  scale_x_continuous("Weeks", breaks=seq(-1,3, by = 1) ) +
  opts( plot.margin = unit(c(0,2,2,1), "lines"),
        legend.position=c(.1,0.9))+
  geom_text(data = test,aes(x=x,y=y_pos,label=n))

p1
```

A different approach of displaying the numbers involves creating a dummy plot below the actual plot. Here is the code:

```
graphics.off()      # close graphics windows   

library(car)
library(ggplot2)  #load ggplot
library(gridExtra) #load Grid
library(RGraphics) # support of the "R graphics" book, on CRAN

#create dummy data
test= data.frame(
  group = c("A", "B", "A","B", "A", "B"), 
  x = c(1 ,1,2,2,3,3 ),
  y = c(33,25,27,36,43,25),
  n=c(71,55,65,58,65,58),
  y_pos=c(15,6,15,6,15,6)
  )


p1 <- qplot(x, y, data=test, colour=group) +
  ylab("Mean change from baseline") + 
  opts(plot.margin = unit(c(1,2,-1,1), "lines")) +
  geom_line()+
  scale_x_continuous("Weeks", breaks=seq(-1,3, by = 1) ) +
  opts(legend.position="bottom",
       legend.title=theme_blank(),
       title.text="Line plot using GGPLOT") 
p1

p2 <- qplot(x, y, data=test, geom="blank")+
  ylab(" ")+
  opts(     plot.margin = unit(c(0,2,-2,1), "lines"),
            axis.line = theme_blank(), 
            axis.ticks = theme_segment(colour = "white"),           
            axis.text.x=theme_text(angle=-90,colour="white"),
            axis.text.y=theme_text(angle=-90,colour="white"),
            panel.background = theme_rect(fill = "transparent",colour = NA), 
            panel.grid.minor = theme_blank(),      
            panel.grid.major = theme_blank()
            )+
  geom_text(data = test,aes(x=x,y=y_pos,label=n)) 
p2

grid.arrange(p1, p2, heights = c(8.5, 1.5),             nrow=2 )
```

However, that is very complicated and would be hard to modify for different data. Ideally, I'd like to be able to pass Y coordinates as percent of the screen.

Comment: annotation_custom() and code [from here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9690648/point-clipped-on-x-axis-in-ggplot) might help you.  See below.

Comment: See my answer below. It is definitely simpler than the accepted answer.

Comment: Recent versions of ggplot2 now have this functionality built in as per the answer below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36036479/170352

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Edited** `opts` has been deprecated, replaced by `theme`; `element_blank` has replaced `theme_blank`; and `ggtitle()` is used in place of `opts(title = ...`

Sandy- thank you so much!!!! This does exactly what I want. I do wish we could control the clipping in geom.text or geom.annotate.

I put together the following program if anybody else is interested.

```
 rm(list = ls())     # clear objects  
 graphics.off()      # close graphics windows   

library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

#create dummy data
test= data.frame(
  group = c("Group 1", "Group 1", "Group 1","Group 2", "Group 2", "Group 2"), 
  x = c(1 ,2,3,1,2,3 ),
  y = c(33,25,27,36,23,25),
  n=c(71,55,65,58,65,58),
  ypos=c(18,18,18,17,17,17)

  )


p1 <- qplot(x=x, y=y, data=test, colour=group) +
  ylab("Mean change from baseline") + 
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(1,3,8,1), "lines")) +
  geom_line()+
  scale_x_continuous("Visits", breaks=seq(-1,3) ) +
  theme(legend.position="bottom",
       legend.title=element_blank())+
   ggtitle("Line plot") 


# Create the textGrobs 
for (ii in 1:nrow(test))
{
  #display numbers at each visit
  p1=p1+ annotation_custom(grob = textGrob(test$n[ii]),  
                           xmin = test$x[ii], 
                           xmax = test$x[ii], 
                           ymin = test$ypos[ii], 
                           ymax = test$ypos[ii])

    #display group text
    if (ii %in% c(1,4)) #there is probably a better way 
      {
    p1=p1+ annotation_custom(grob = textGrob(test$group[ii]),  
                             xmin = 0.85, 
                             xmax = 0.85, 
                             ymin = test$ypos[ii], 
                             ymax = test$ypos[ii])
    }

  }




  # Code to override clipping
  gt <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p1))
  gt$layout$clip[gt$layout$name=="panel"] <- "off"
  grid.draw(gt)
```

[image]

Comment: It doesn't look right here, does the code still work for you?

Answer (score 25):

The current version (>2.1) has a `+ labs(caption = "text")`, which displays an annotation below the plot. This is themeable (font properties,... left/right aligned). See https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/pull/1582 for examples.

Answer (score 20):

**Updated** `opts()` has been replaced with `theme()`

In the code below, a base plot is drawn, with a wider margin at the bottom of the plot. The textGrob is created, then inserted into the plot using annotation_custom(). Except the text is not visible because it is outside the plot panel - the output is clipped to the panel. But using baptiste's code [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9690648/point-clipped-on-x-axis-in-ggplot), the clipping can be overrridden. The position is in terms of data units, and both text labels are centred.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)

# Base plot
df = data.frame(x=seq(1:10), y = seq(1:10))
p = ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point() + ylim(0,10) +
    theme(plot.margin = unit(c(1,1,3,1), "cm"))
p

# Create the textGrobs
Text1 = textGrob(paste("Largest x-value is", round(max(df$x), 2), sep = " "))
Text2 = textGrob(paste("Mean = ", mean(df$x), sep = ""))

p1 = p + annotation_custom(grob = Text1,  xmin = 4, xmax = 4, ymin = -3, ymax = -3) +
        annotation_custom(grob = Text2,  xmin = 8, xmax = 8, ymin = -3, ymax = -3)
p1

# Code to override clipping
gt <- ggplotGrob(p1)
gt$layout$clip[gt$layout$name=="panel"] <- "off"
grid.draw(gt)
```

[image]

Or, using `grid` functions to create and position the label.

```
p
grid.text((paste("Largest x-value is", max(df$x), sep = " ")),
   x = unit(.2, "npc"), y = unit(.1, "npc"), just = c("left", "bottom"), 
   gp = gpar(fontface = "bold", fontsize = 18, col = "blue"))
```

[image]

**Edit**
Or, add text grob using gtable functions.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
library(gtable)

# Base plot
df = data.frame(x=seq(1:10), y = seq(1:10))
p = ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point() + ylim(0,10) 

# Construct the text grob
lab = textGrob((paste("Largest x-value is", max(df$x), sep = " ")),
   x = unit(.1, "npc"), just = c("left"), 
   gp = gpar(fontface = "bold", fontsize = 18, col = "blue"))


gp = ggplotGrob(p)

# Add a row below the 2nd from the bottom
gp = gtable_add_rows(gp, unit(2, "grobheight", lab), -2)

# Add 'lab' grob to that row, under the plot panel
gp = gtable_add_grob(gp, lab, t = -2, l = gp$layout[gp$layout$name == "panel",]$l)

grid.newpage()
grid.draw(gp)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I realize that Grid functions allow to place text anywhere on the device. I am just wondering if this possible to place text BELOW the plot, yet somehow use the X coordinates from the plot. i.e something similar to what you could with text function in base R.

Comment: Thanks! I am getting Error: could not find function "ggplot_gtable"
> gt$layout$clip[gt$layout$name=="panel"] <- "off"

Comment: It's a function in `ggplot2`. What version of ggplot2 are you using? You might need to upgrade. The latest version is 0.9.0

Comment: Sandy: The R studio somehow kept installing the older version of GGPLOT. Sorry about that.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. How do I get the updated version if not from CRAN?

Comment: And, per the mailist discussion about 0.9.0, have all of the dependency issues been addressed?

Comment: @Atticus29 I don't use Rstudio so i can't help you. There is a discussion forum on the [Rstudio website](http://support.rstudio.org/). The latest ggplot2 version is 0.9.1.

Answer (score 6):

Actually the best answer and easiest solution is to use the cowplot package.

Version 0.5.0 of the cowplot package (on CRAN) handles ggplot2 subtitles using the add_sub function.

Use it like so:

```
  diamondsCubed <-ggplot(aes(carat, price), data = diamonds) + 
  geom_point() + 
  scale_x_continuous(trans = cuberoot_trans(), limits = c(0.2, 3),
                     breaks = c(0.2, 0.5, 1, 2, 3)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(trans = log10_trans(), limits = c(350, 15000),
                     breaks = c(350, 1000, 5000, 10000, 15000)) +
  ggtitle('Price log10 by Cube-Root of Carat') +
  theme_xkcd()


  ggdraw(add_sub(diamondsCubed, "This is an annotation.\nAnnotations can span multiple lines."))
```