# Axis labels for each bar and each group in bar charts with dodged groups

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to create a bar chart using `ggplot2` with dodged groups and axis labels for both the bars (male, female) and the groups (Study 1, Study 2...). Here is how I would like my chart to look:

[image]

And some R code. In this case, only the groups are labeled on the axis (not the bars within the group). The bar labels in the axis basically replace the legend.

```
x      = runif(8)
gender = factor(c("male","female","male","female","male","female","male","female"))
group  = c(0,0,1,1,2,2,3,3)
df     = data.frame(x,gender,group)

ggplot(df,aes(x=group,y=x,fill=gender)) + 
    geom_bar(stat="identity",position="dodge") + 
    scale_x_continuous("",breaks=c(0:3),
        labels=c('G1','G2','G3','G4'))
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Inspired by @Sandy Muspratt answer on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10014187/displaying-text-below-the-plot-generated-by-ggplot2).

First, create and save as object plot that has no legend and change x axis labels to `Female` or `Male` with `scale_x_continuous()`. Add extra space under the plot with `plot.margin=` in `theme()`.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
p<-ggplot(df,aes(x=group,y=x,fill=gender)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity",position="dodge") + 
  scale_x_continuous("",breaks=c(-0.25,0.25,0.75,1.25,1.75,2.25,2.75,3.25),
                     labels=rep(c("Female","Male"),times=4))+
  theme(legend.position="none")+
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(1,2,3,1), "lines"))
```

Now with functions `annotation_custom()` and `textGrob()` add labels `Study 1`, `Study 2` under the plot setting x and y coordinates (negative coordinates for y puts labels under the plot).

```
p1<-p+annotation_custom(grob=textGrob("Study 1"),
                          xmin=0,xmax=0,ymin=-.2,ymax=-0.2)+
      annotation_custom(grob=textGrob("Study 2"),
                          xmin=1,xmax=1,ymin=-.2,ymax=-0.2)+
      annotation_custom(grob=textGrob("Study 3"),
                          xmin=2,xmax=2,ymin=-.2,ymax=-0.2)+
      annotation_custom(grob=textGrob("Study 4"),
                          xmin=3,xmax=3,ymin=-.2,ymax=-0.2)
```

To ensure that new labels are plotted, you should convert plot to grobs object and then disable clipping.

```
gt <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p1))
gt$layout$clip[gt$layout$name=="panel"] <- "off"
grid.draw(gt)
```

[image]