# Barplot in R/ggplot with multiple factors

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a table which I would like to make into a plot using ggplot2 and I've been unsuccessful so far.
I have prepared a simplified table that looks like this

```
df1<-data.frame(Loc=c(rep("L1",5),rep("L2",3),rep("L3",4)),
Type=c(rep("T1",3),rep("T2",2),"T1","T2","T2","T1","T1","T2","T2"),
       y2009=rep("A",12),y2010=c("A","B","A","A","A","A","B","B","A","A","B","B"),
       y2011=c("B","B","B","A","B",rep("B",4),"A","B","B"))
df1
```

Loc has 3 locations.Each location has 2 types of samples T1 or T2. They start in 2009 as A and over time some becomes B. So, by 2011, there are lots of B.

This is the figure I have so far

```
ggplot(df1,aes(x=Type)) + geom_bar()+facet_grid(~Loc)
ggplot(df1,aes(x=y2009,fill=Type)) + geom_bar(position="dodge")+facet_grid(~Loc)
```

[image]
[image]

I am not quite sure how to get counts from three factors.

I would like a figure similar to below which I roughly drafted in paint. The facets are locations and I have made the bars only for Loc1 as example.
[image]

Comment: This will help you make a start http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/, and you might be interested in stacked barplots and facets in particular/

Comment: you are almost there,  look into `melt` from `reshape2`

Comment: hmmm.. all columns in the table are factors. Does melt do anything to factors? I thought it only did something if a column with numbers or integers are present.

Comment: melt is specifically to add one more column of factors, and removing those columns

Comment: @Ananta I may be mistaken, but I don't think this is going to be very easy.

Comment: @joran doesn't `lattice` have some facilities for an x-axis hierarchy like this?

Comment: @Justin Possibly, it's been so long since I've delved into lattice. Henrik showed one route (though there are still some issues with it) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11620735/324364) might have some other general ideas.

Comment: @joran, yeah, but have to use var, value interaction and might need to add one level 2009.B manually, as there is no such combination, if he wants to show A and B for each year, let's see where he goes

Comment: @Ananta I agree with the general strategy, just think it's going to be a little work. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16279295/324364) will also probably be useful to get the axis labels right.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try multi-level facets:

```
df2 <- melt(df1, id.vars=c("Loc", "Type"))
ggplot(data=df2, aes(x=value, fill=Type)) + 
  geom_bar() + facet_wrap(~ Loc + variable, nrow=1)
```

[image]

Or alternatively, `facet_grid`, which I think looks better but doesn't quite match your sketch:

```
df2 <- melt(df1, id.vars=c("Loc", "Type"))
ggplot(data=df2, aes(x=value, fill=Type)) + 
  geom_bar() + facet_grid(Loc ~ variable)
```

[image]

Finally, borrowing [from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847559/conditionally-change-panel-background-with-facet-grid), you could try to better distinguish the locations by color (clearly color scheme could use some work, but you get the point):

```
df2 <- melt(df1, id.vars=c("Loc", "Type"))
ggplot(data=df2, aes(x=value, fill=Type)) + 
  geom_rect(aes(fill=Loc),xmin =-Inf,xmax=Inf,ymin=-Inf,ymax=Inf,alpha = 0.1) +
  geom_bar() +
  facet_wrap(~ Loc + variable, nrow=1)
```

[image]

If you want to actually have separate panels for each location, I think you'll have to use generate your own grid viewports and grobs.  There was a package `ggextra` that did stuff like this, but it doesn't seem to be available for the most recent R versions.