# Is there a R function to plot ggplot under for loop

Tags: r

I have a dataframe df. I need to plot the variables that are factor. For example here it is x,a and b

```
   df
   x y g  a  b
 1 a 2 1  df df
 2 a 3 2  fg fg
 3 b 4 1  gf gf
 4 b 5 2  fd fd
```

I have written a code below but I am not able to execute

```
  as <- names(Filter(is.factor, df))
  for(i in 1:length(as))
  {
  ssa <- ggplot(data=df,aes_string(x=as[i],fill=as[i]))+geom_bar(stat = 
  "count")
  }
```

Comment: Hi User. I did see this but this is not solving my problem. I need to have 3 plots at a time for x, a and b

Comment: I have edited the code for you. the issues ssa is returning the last plot. What about the first 2 plots

Comment: Have a look at dput function...

Comment: Does that help https://stackoverflow.com/q/20953594/5784831?

Comment: Hi Christoph, Nope. I am aware of multiple plots but I need that in for loop. Can you please run my code and see. I am getting the final plot. I am not able to store first 2 plots in ssa

Comment: @RferR, it is quite unclear what you are asking. I'd suggest editing your question specifying whether you need the plots to be `side by side` as in `par(mfrow = c( r, c )` if one used base R (here one could use the `gridExtra` package) or if you need the visuals to be in the same plot as in stacked bar chars or side by side bar charts? Currently the question is ambigous as such answers and comments will be mislead.

Comment: Feel free to draw the end figure by hand to illustrate what you're after. Right now it's not very clear to me, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

An immediate fix to your code is to add index to store objects.

```
library(ggplot2)

ssa <- vector("list", length(as))

for(i in 1:length(as)) {
   ssa[[i]] <- ggplot(data=df,aes_string(x=as[i],fill=as[i])) + 
               geom_bar(stat = "count")
}
```

Now you have all three objects in `ssa[[1]]`, `ssa[[2]]` and `ssa[[3]]` respectively.

However, there are better ways to do the same thing. You can use `lapply`

```
plot_obj <- lapply(df[as], function(x) 
            ggplot(data= df, aes(x, fill = x)) + geom_bar(stat = "count"))
```

Or maybe use `facets` after gathering the data to long format.

```
tidyr::gather(df[as]) %>%
   ggplot() + aes(value, fill = value) + geom_bar(stat = "count") + 
   facet_wrap(.~key)
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect thanks. Can we arrange the plots in the layout? Say, I need the third plot in the second row

Comment: @RferR You can use `factor` to adjust order.  Do `tidyr::gather(df[as]) %>%
  mutate(key = factor(key, levels = c("a", "x", "b"))) %>%
  ggplot() + aes(value, fill = value) + geom_bar(stat = "count") + 
  facet_wrap(.~key)`

Comment: Nope. The thing is I did not understand the above code. That is the reason i have asked a question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57545652/is-there-a-r-function-to-adjust-layout-under-for-loop

Comment: Can you try to modify my code there?