# Label bar plot's group members on x-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I'm trying to generate two kinds of labels on the x axis with `R` ggplot2 package.

One is based on x axis's value (which I have already done), another one is based on `pathId` (showing on the bar). Currently I'm putting them inside the bar using `geom_text`.

**Is there a way to put them under the x axis?**

I see some questions here but they are based on stack bar or use `x=interaction(var1,var2)`. But in that way each bar will have the same distance, which is not what I want.

Here is the data I generated by `summarySE`:

```
          pathId nodeId   N    value        sd        se       ci  
1  least similar      0 216 159.7242  96.74438  6.582622 12.97474  
2  least similar      1 165 146.0958 123.27584  9.597011 18.94963  
3   less similar      0 216 185.6628 149.27098 10.156604 20.01927  
4   less similar      1 152 152.0290 135.02925 10.952318 21.63958  
5        similar      0 216 179.3326 150.55189 10.243758 20.19105  
6        similar      1 141 163.1733 111.77780  9.413389 18.61077  
7   more similar      0 216 183.8146 123.51216  8.403938 16.56466  
8   more similar      1  90 179.3577 141.21904 14.885794 29.57775  
9   most similar      0 216 187.6143 107.80367  7.335111 14.45794  
10  most similar      1  61 184.9422 117.32353 15.021738 30.04795
```

And the code I'm using is:

```
ggplot(data=bar_data, aes(x=interaction(nodeId), y=value, order=pathId), fill="grey80",colour="grey80")+
geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge", fill="grey95", colour="black", show_guide=FALSE)+
geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=value-se, ymax=value+se, order=pathId), width=.15,
              colour="black", position=position_dodge(width=0.90))+
ylab("BM25 Score")+
xlab("Node")+  
scale_x_discrete(breaks= c(0,1),
                 labels=c("BM25(Node0, Node1)","BM25(Node1, Node2"))+
geom_text(data=bar_data, aes(label=pathId, y=30),position=position_dodge(width=0.9),angle=75)+
theme(legend.title=element_text(size=14), legend.text=element_text(size=12))+
theme_bw()+
theme(axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
      panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
      panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
      panel.border = element_blank(),
      panel.background = element_blank())
```

This graph is what I get.
[image: original R graph]

And this is what I want, I also want the label for group members can be rotated so I could write longer string for each of them.

[image]

Comment: this may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16279295/axis-labels-for-each-bar-and-each-group-in-bar-charts-with-dodged-groups

Comment: This may help too: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18165863/]. Also this: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20571306/]

Comment: @Ananta thanks for your help, I have tried this solution but I get `Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale`