# axis labels for each bar and each group in R barchart

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I am trying to create axis labels for each bar and each group in a bar chart with dodged groups. Related question here: [Axis labels for each bar and each group in bar charts with dodged groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16279295/axis-labels-for-each-bar-and-each-group-in-bar-charts-with-dodged-groups)

I want the end result to look something like this but with 3 groups with 4 bars each
[image]

I have added example data below

I have played around with `scale_x_discrete` and `scale_x_continuous` but it doesnt seem to work.

```
# create a dataset 
specie <- c(rep("sorgho" , 3) , rep("poacee" , 3) , rep("banana" , 3) , rep("triticum" , 3) )
condition <- rep(c("normal" , "stress" , "Nitrogen") , 4)
value <- abs(rnorm(12 , 0 , 15))
df <- data.frame(specie,condition,value)
df


# Grouped
set.seed(123)
df

ggplot(df, aes(fill = specie, y = value, x = condition)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = position_dodge(width = 0.9), width = 0.6) +
  scale_fill_manual(
    "specie",
    values = c("black", "black", "black", "black"),
    
  ) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill=NA, size=1),
        text = element_text(size = 8, family = "sans"),
  ) + labs(x = "Nitrogen                  normal          stress", y = expression(paste("Total Phytoplankton Abundance (", x10^{6}, "cells/L)"))) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0))  +   
  theme(legend.position="none") + scale_x_discrete("", breaks=c(-0.25,0.25,0.75,1.25,1.75,2.25,2.75,3.25,3.75,4.25,4.75,5.25),
                     labels=rep(c("sorgho","poacee", "banana", "triticum"),times=3))
```

current output
[image]

```scale_x_discrete`` removes all x axis labels for some reason.

Comment: Is this duplicate more helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18165863/multirow-axis-labels-with-nested-grouping-variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something like this?

```r
ggplot(df, aes(specie, value, fill = specie)) +
  geom_col(fill = "gray80") +
  geom_col(alpha = 0.5) +
  facet_grid(.~condition, switch = "x") +
  scale_x_discrete(NULL, expand = c(0.1, 0.5)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(0, 30)) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1", guide = "none") +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 20) +
  theme(strip.placement = "outside",
        panel.spacing.x = unit(0, "mm"),
        panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 12),
        axis.ticks.x = element_line(color = "gray"),
        axis.line.x = element_line())
```

[image]