# How can I add a methodological note to a plot ?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I use the ggplot2 package in R. Most of the time, I'd like to add a note below the plot for specifying the source and or my methodology but unfortunately, I've never found any option for that. Does anyone has a solution ?

Comment: Use `grid::grid.text` in conjunction with `gridExtra::grid.arrange`?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10014187/displaying-text-below-the-plot-generated-by-ggplot2) may help.