# Add additional text below the legend (R + ggplot)

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

Assume we have this simple plot:

```
ggplot(data = msleep, aes(x = log(bodywt), y = sleep_total)) + 
    geom_point(aes(color = vore)) + 
    theme(legend.position="bottom")
```

[image]

Is it possible to add a text below the legend items? I know how to add a title (above) the legend. But lets say I want some other general information written below.

Would be very pleased to find a solution to that.

Thanks!
Martin

Comment: @hrbrmstr I think this is a duplicate but not of what you posted.  It's related but that's about a table.  I think this is the dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10346760/1000343

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is one possible approach:

```
library(gridExtra)
library(grid)

p <- ggplot(data = msleep, aes(x = log(bodywt), y = sleep_total)) + 
    geom_point(aes(color = vore)) + 
    theme(legend.position="bottom", plot.margin = unit(c(1,1,3,1),"lines")) + 
    annotation_custom(grob = textGrob("Extra text.  Read all about it"),  
        xmin = 2, xmax = 2, ymin = -4.5, ymax = -4.55)


gt <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p))
gt$layout$clip[gt$layout$name=="panel"] <- "off"
grid.draw(gt)
```

[image]

Comment: I figured this has been covered before so I searched.  Here's a pretty related post with a ton more info: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10346760/1000343

Comment: on running this code I do not see any text at the bottom ??