# Placing labels outside of the strips in facet_grid

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-grid

I wonder that how can we place labels `left` or `right` side of the `facet_grid` strips.

As a reproducible example I would like to start with this example

```
library(ggplot2)
    ggplot(mtcars, aes("", hp)) + 
      geom_boxplot(width=0.7, position=position_dodge(0.7)) + 
      theme_bw() +
      facet_grid(. ~ vs + am + carb,switch = 'both',labeller = label_both) +
      theme(panel.spacing=unit(0.2,"lines"),
            strip.background=element_rect(color="grey30", fill="grey90"),
            panel.border=element_rect(color="grey90"),
            axis.ticks.x=element_blank())+
            #strip.placement="outside") +
      labs(x="")
```

[image]

The plot which I look for;

[image]

Comment: Don't think can be done "directly". Try plotting as you have in the second graph, then call something like `grid.text("vs", x = 0.98 , y = 0.1)`, though you'll have to fiddle the numbers to get it exactly where you need it.

Comment: E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/29594608/2706826

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can always add the titles manually to the gtable,

[image]

```
g <- ggplotGrob(p)

library(gtable)
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)
pos <- subset(g$layout, grepl("strip",name))
titles <- tableGrob(c("vs","am","carb"), theme = ttheme_minimal(9))
titles$heights <- unit(rep(1,3), "null")
g$widths[ncol(g)] <- sum(titles$widths)
g <- gtable_add_grob(g, titles, t=unique(pos$t), l = ncol(g)) 
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(g)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually I was looking for this kind of answer as I am also trying to merge common strips into one common strip as in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40732543/seeking-workaround-for-gtable-add-grob-code-broken-by-ggplot-2-2-0) . Is is possible to add these lines into the `OverlappingStripLabels` ?

Comment: as `pos` will have two different definition.

Comment: Hi @baptiste did you able to look up to my last comments? I have tried some but still unable merge your solution to `OverlappingStripLabels()`