# How to place a text on a free position in a ggplot2 plot

Tags: r, text, ggplot2, label, facet

If I use the following code

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) + geom_point() + facet_wrap(~cyl, ncol = 2)
p
```

I obviously get a chart with one blank facet in the SE corner ([resulting chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTlFU.png)). I'd like to place some text into this blank facet providing e.g. an explanation or any other information pertinent to the chart. I haven't yet found a solution, all solutions place the text in the filled facets.

Thanks for your help!

Ulrich

Answer (score 0):

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) + geom_point() + facet_wrap(~cyl, ncol = 2)
p
library(grid)
grid.text("your text", x = 0.75, y = 0.25)
```

[see the answer that i got here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29594348/how-to-position-annotate-text-in-the-blank-area-of-facet-ggplot)