# Add n, mean and sd as numbers/numerics under boxplots with labels aligned under y-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, mean, standard-deviation

Im aware of that [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10014187/displaying-text-below-the-plot-generated-by-ggplot2), but the solution looks kinda long and complicated to me: Is there a quick and easy solution? To add the following vector under the y-axis?

```
yLabels <- c("","","n","mn","sd")
```

Reproducible data:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(magrittr)

mtcars <- mtcars

values <- rbind(tapply(mtcars$mpg,mtcars$gear,length)) %>% rbind(tapply(mtcars$mpg,mtcars$gear,mean)) %>% rbind(tapply(mtcars$mpg,mtcars$gear,sd)) %>%
  round(3)

levels <- rbind(levels(mtcars$gear%>%factor),matrix("",ncol=ncol(values)))

xlabs <- rbind(levels,values) %>% apply(.,2,function(x) {paste(x,collapse="\n")}) 
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=factor(gear), y=mpg, fill=factor(gear))) + geom_boxplot() + scale_x_discrete(labels=xlabs)
```

This is what the above code processes:

[image: Missing Labels to explain numerics]

This is what i want: Labels under and "in line" with the y-axis. For n, mean and sd

[image]

Comment: does this maybe help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12409960/ggplot2-annotate-outside-of-plot

Comment: no it doesnt help

Comment: the codes i found need "specific" ylab positions (in my case maybe 8 etc..) i want a general solution to just paste (n,mn,sd) into that position. no matter what the scaling is. It already works with the xlabels. it a general approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the nicest solution but gives you maybe an idea how to solve it in a general way...

```
xlabs <- c('2.5'='\n\nn\nmn\nsd', 
           rbind(levels,values) %>% apply(.,2,function(x) {paste(x,collapse="\n")})) 
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=gear, y=mpg, fill=factor(gear))) + 
  geom_boxplot() + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(2.5,3,4,5), labels=xlabs) +
  theme(axis.ticks.x=element_line(color=c('white', rep('black', length(xlabs[-1])))))
```

I think a trick would be to use numeric values instead of the factor and you could add a tick label close to your limits. This one can than be labeled and the tick mark is white in the and...

Pretty hacky but I guess there is potential...

**EDIT**

Ok, a little bit more general in case of factors:

```
mtcars$test <- as.factor(mtcars$gear)
xlabs <- 
  c('2.5'='\n\nn\nmn\nsd', 
    rbind(levels,values) %>% 
      apply(.,2,function(x) {paste(x,collapse="\n")})) 

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=as.numeric(test), y=mpg, fill=factor(gear))) + 
  geom_boxplot() + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(0.5, seq(1,length(levels(mtcars$test)))), 
                     labels=xlabs) +
  theme(axis.ticks.x=element_line(color=c('white', 
                                          rep('black', length(xlabs[-1])))))
```

Factors can be represented `as.numeric` and then these are basically integers starting at 1. So you can just use this to put them on the continuous scale and add an extra break at 0 or 0.5 and add your extra label to the `xlabs` variable. To hide the tick mark you can just add a white tick plus the number of levels in your column used for the x axis.

Comment: this looks very good in this case!!! Now i need to find out how i can get the "2.5" automatically. How did you come up with 2.5 ? Trial and Error?

Comment: what should i use when groups are "categories" like "g1", "g2" and "g3".

Comment: Can give u an example tomorrow... But you can use as.numeric to convert your factors into a sequence starting at 1 so you can just at a break at 0.1 and this should work...

Comment: would be great. I transformed the gears to a b and c. nothing works anymore: mtcars$gear[mtcars$gear==3] <- "a"
mtcars$gear[mtcars$gear==4] <- "b"
mtcars$gear[mtcars$gear==5] <- "c"

Comment: I added an example with factors... So here basically the factors have numbers starting at 1... Just add a break at .5 or 0 and modify the labels. If you have a lot labels this might overprint... But not sure how to solve this in a general way.

Comment: thank you for taking the time. I believe i can construct a general solution with your very valuable input! I will post it here when its good and ready.

Comment: Would be nice if you could than except my answer :-) looking forward to a solid implementation

Answer (score 0):

With the valuable help of drmariod i came up with the following general solution:

1: the variable "xorigin" holds the x-value directly under the y-axis

2: met = metric-Variable , cat = categorial-Variable

```
library(ggplot2)
library(magrittr)

## Change only right sides to your needs ##
ds      <- diamonds
catName <- "cut"
metName <- "price"
###########################################

names(ds)[match(catName,names(ds))] <- "catVar"
names(ds)[match(metName,names(ds))] <- "metVar"

values <- rbind(tapply(ds$metVar,ds$catVar,length)) %>% rbind(tapply(ds$metVar,ds$catVar,mean)) %>% rbind(tapply(ds$metVar,ds$catVar,sd)) %>%
          round(3)
if (!is.factor(ds$catVar)) {
  ds$catVar <- factor(ds$catVar, levels=colnames(values))
}

levels <- rbind(levels(ds$catVar),matrix("",ncol=ncol(values)))

xlabs <- 
  c('2.5'='\n\nn\nmn\nsd', 
    rbind(levels,values) %>% 
      apply(.,2,function(x) {paste(x,collapse="\n")})) 

p <- ggplot(ds, aes(x=as.numeric(catVar), y=metVar, fill=factor(catVar))) + 
  geom_boxplot()
xorigin <- ggplot_build(p)$panel$ranges[[1]][[1]][1]
rm(p)


ggplot(ds, aes(x=as.numeric(catVar), y=metVar, fill=factor(catVar))) + 
  geom_boxplot() + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(xorigin, seq(1,length(levels(ds$catVar)))), 
                     labels=xlabs) +
  theme(axis.ticks.x=element_line(color=c('white', 
                                          rep('black', length(xlabs[-1]))))) +
  xlab(catName) +
  ylab(metName) +
  labs(fill=catName)
```

[image]