# ggplot2: Draw geom_segment() outside of the plot area

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a two facet plots created in ggplot2. I would like to add an arrow outside of the plot area. Multiple questions tried to address this:
[How to draw lines outside of plot area in ggplot2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10525957/how-to-draw-lines-outside-of-plot-area-in-ggplot2)
[Displaying text below the plot generated by ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10014187/displaying-text-below-the-plot-generated-by-ggplot2)

but I can't make my example work. Also, I hope there is an easier way to accomplish this?

I tried to increase `plot.margins` and to use `coord_cartesian()`, but neither helped.

[image]

Instead, I want:

[image]

My dummy example:

```
# read library to assess free data
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)


ggplot(tips,
       aes(x=total_bill,
           y=tip/total_bill)) + 
  geom_point(shape=1) +
  facet_grid(. ~ sex) +
  # define the segment outside the plot
  geom_segment(aes(x = 10, 
                   y = -0.25, 
                   xend = 10, 
                   yend = 0),
               col = "red",
               arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.3, "cm"))) +
  theme_bw() +
  # limit the displayed plot extent
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 0.75)) +
  # increase plot margins - does not help
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(1,1,1,0), "lines"))
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can draw outside the panel using the argument `clip="off"` in `coord_cartesian`. I also use the `expand` argument of `scale_y` to start the y-axis at zero. There is a bit a manual selection over the `y` start position.

So your example

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(tips,
       aes(x=total_bill,
           y=tip/total_bill)) + 
  geom_point(shape=1) +
  facet_grid(. ~ sex) +
  annotate("segment", x=12, y=-0.05, xend=12, yend=0,
               col="red", arrow=arrow(length=unit(0.3, "cm"))) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0))+
  theme_bw() +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 0.75), clip="off") +
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(1,1,1,0), "lines"))
```

(I changed `geom_segment` to `annotate` as you were not mapping aesthetics)

Which produces

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer @user20650! Please, can you include also a resulting plot in it? Everybody than can see the resulting plot without the need to rerun the code in their R environment.

Comment: coord_cartesian is shifting some of the plotted points outside the plot area.

Comment: what do you mean @HermanToothrot; is it that if points are right on the axes border, after using `clip` that some of the point is outside the plot panel?? or

Comment: The points in the upper part of the plot are cut off, I had to set ylim = c(0, 1). I am just suggesting that your solution might not work for all plots.

Comment: Hi @HermanToothrot ; ah right got you. okay yes the limits are plot specific

Answer (score 3):

This is a workaround which is not exactly super satisfying, because you will need to play around with the position of your plots. Principally it uses custom annotation, possible with `cowplot`

```
library(ggplot2) 
library(cowplot)
library(reshape2)
```

First define your plots, with the same coordinate limits.

```
p <- 
  ggplot(tips, aes(x = total_bill, y = tip/total_bill)) + 
  geom_point(shape = 1) +
  facet_grid(. ~ sex) +
  theme_bw() +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 0.75), xlim = c(0, 50)) 

arrow_p <- 
  ggplot(tips) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = 1, y = -1, xend = 1, yend = 0),
               col = "red",
               arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.3, "cm"))) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 0.75), xlim = c(0,50)) +
  theme_void()
```

`arrow_p` is created on a void background for use as overlay. You can now position it where you want with:

```
 ggdraw() +
    draw_plot(p) +
    draw_plot(arrow_p, x = 0.10, y = 0.05) +
    draw_plot(arrow_p, x = 0.57, y = 0.05)
```

[image]

Unfortunately, you have to trial-and-error here. You can also change specify the width/height/scale parameters of `draw_plot()`.
There might be a better way, but this is a fairly straight forward workaround...

Comment: thank you for your answer, this is very interesting approach!