# Add a transparent window/keyhole ggplot2 (grid)

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-grid

Sometimes it is helpful to use a technique of adding a gray semi-transparent layer to an image and then cutting a keyhole into that layer to highlight a certain portion of the image below.  Here is an example from a [youtube vide](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BlvKWEvKSi8#t=215):

[image]

I do this with plots sometimes but use Inkscape to add a semitransparent layer and then use the eraser to cut a hole in that layer.  This (a) looks less than professional (b) requires extra time and a separate program and (c) possible loss in quality.

I want to do it in R.  I'm asking about ggplot2 because this is my tool of choice but I think any grid answer would be good (I know base probably has a very different approach).

So here is a MWE where I've added a `geom_rect` to show where we'd want to cut the keyhole/window:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) + 
    geom_point(size=3) +    
    geom_rect(mapping=aes(xmin=20, xmax=25, 
        ymin=3, ymax=3.3), color="black", alpha=.01)
```

How can I use R to make a plot that looks something like this:

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure of a direct-way, but an indirect way would be to plot the four rectangles AROUND the hole.

Comment: It be nice if it went outside the plot area too otherwise the eye would be drawn there

Comment: You would not want the axis to be readable?

Comment: Not in the case I'm using it for.

Comment: Perhaps you can use `annote_cusotm` [similar to here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12409960/ggplot2-annotate-outside-of-plot)

Comment: Looking at the answers, I wonder if anyone could do the same thing - but make it a circle instead of a rectangle?

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen - see below for circles.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Turns out you can do this with `grid.path(...)` in `grid` package. Read the [documentation](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/grid/grid.path) to see how to create a path with a hole in it.

```
library(gridExtra)
library(ggplot2)

ggp <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) + geom_point(size=3)
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(arrangeGrob(ggp))
grid.path(c(0,0,1,1,.48,.48,.62,.62),
                    c(0,1,1,0,.43,.50,.50,.43),
                    id=rep(1:2, each=4),
                    rule="evenodd",gp=gpar(fill="black", alpha=0.6))
```

[image]

NB: `grid.draw(...)` and `grid.path(...)` are in the `grid` package; `arrangeGrob(...)` is in the `gridExtra` package. Loading `gridExtra` causes `grid` to be loaded. Thanks to @MartinBel for suggesting the edit.

In response to @BrandonBertelsen comment: `grid.path(...)` is agnostic about shape; you just have to supply the coordinates.

```
center <- c(x=0.55,y=0.48)
r      <- 0.1
circle <- do.call(rbind,lapply(seq(0,2*pi,length=36),
                               function(th)c(x=r*cos(th),y=r*sin(th))))
circle <- data.frame(circle)
circle$x <- circle$x + center["x"]
circle$y <- circle$y + center["y"]

ggp <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) + geom_point(size=3)
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(arrangeGrob(ggp))
grid.path(c(0,0,1,1,circle[,1]),
          c(0,1,1,0,circle[,2]),
          id=c(1,1,1,1,rep(2,nrow(circle))),
          rule="evenodd",gp=gpar(fill="black", alpha=0.6))
```

[image]

The "circle" is an ellipse because of the plot window's aspect ratio.

---

Further reading: [It’s Not What You Draw, It’s What You Don’t Draw](http://journal.r-project.org/archive/2012-2/RJournal_2012-2_Murrell2.pdf) by Paul Murrell in the R Journal

Comment: All terrific responses.  I think this one was the most straight forward. +1

Comment: where does this `grid.draw(arrangeGrob())` habit come from? A simple `print()` seems more logical for drawing a single plot.

Comment: My apologies I never gave this the green check.

Answer (score 7):

How about the following?

```
P <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) + geom_point(size=3) 

## Set the limits for x & y
xlims <- c(20, 25)
ylims <- c(3, 3.3)


# Where P is the original plot
P + geom_rect(mapping=aes(xmin=-Inf, xmax=min(xlims), ymin=-Inf, ymax=+Inf), fill="black", alpha=.01) +
    geom_rect(mapping=aes(xmin=min(xlims), xmax=+Inf, ymin=max(ylims), ymax=+Inf), fill="black", alpha=.01) +
    geom_rect(mapping=aes(xmin=min(xlims), xmax=+Inf, ymin=-Inf, ymax=min(ylims)), fill="black", alpha=.01) +
    geom_rect(mapping=aes(xmin=max(xlims), xmax=+Inf, ymin=min(ylims), ymax=max(ylims)), fill="black", alpha=.01)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response.  This got the ball rolling.  For other searchers this approach may be exactly what they're after.  +1

Answer (score 5):

```
require(ggplot2)

#represent some tiles based on your axes (10 x 10, by 1) deoending on resolution you want
alpha_tiles<-expand.grid(x=0:10,y=0:10,a=0.6)

#set alpha to 0 for the coordinate
alpha_tiles[alpha_tiles$x %in% 7:9 & alpha_tiles$y==7,]$a<-0

qplot(0:10,0:10, size=10, color="red") + theme_bw() +
  geom_raster(data=alpha_tiles,aes(x=x,y=y), alpha=alpha_tiles$a, fill="grey")
```

[image]

or this for a more complete answer that blanks the entire plot:

```
require(ggplot2)

#represent some tiles based on your axes (here 100 x 100, by 1) depending on resolution you want
resolution<-100
alpha_tiles<-expand.grid(x=0:resolution,y=0:resolution,a=0.6)

#set alpha to 0 for the coordinates to highlight
alpha_tiles[alpha_tiles$x %in% 40:70 & alpha_tiles$y %in% 70:80,]$a<-0
alpha_tiles[alpha_tiles$x %in% 10:30 & alpha_tiles$y %in% 10:25,]$a<-0

p<-qplot(0:10,0:10, size=10, color="red") + theme_bw() # background plot


qplot(0:resolution,0:resolution,geom="blank") + theme(axis.line=element_blank(),
                                     axis.text.x=element_blank(),
                                     axis.text.y=element_blank(),
                                     axis.ticks=element_blank(),
                                     axis.title.x=element_blank(),
                                     axis.title.y=element_blank(),
                                     legend.position="none",
                                     panel.background=element_blank(),
                                     panel.border=element_blank(),
                                     panel.grid.major=element_blank(),
                                     panel.grid.minor=element_blank(),
                                     plot.background=element_blank()) +
  annotation_custom(ggplotGrob(p),0,resolution,0,resolution) +
geom_raster(data=alpha_tiles,aes(x=x,y=y), alpha=alpha_tiles$a, fill="grey")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your ideas.  I was about to check this when I saw a coordinate based response from jlhoward.  +1