# Two column x-axis in ggplot2 (group by first, specify second)

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have quarterly data as follows (key represents year-quarter):

```
       tic    saleq    key
1     AAPL 1346.202 1990-2
2     AAPL 1364.760 1990-3
3     NOK  1354.090 1990-4
```

Because it now is in a single column, I'm able to plot the line with the combined column as the x-axis:

```
p <- ggplot(example, aes(x = key, y = saleq))
p + geom_line(aes(color=tic, group=tic)) + ylab("Quarterly sales")
```

However, this (logically) generates a lot of duplicate 'year' values (ie. x column is littered 2014-1, 2014-2)

I'd like to be able to plot this with ggplot2 by 'grouping' by year & then showing the quarter just above it on the x-axis. Similar to plotting a line graph in Excel as with this data. Is something like this possible in ggplot2?

[image: example excel graph]

I've been forwarded to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26294883/adding-more-x-axix-labels-in-ggplot/26295796#26295796), which tries something similar. However, this does not take into account naming multiple 'groups' of x-values: would I have to dynamically calculate where the middle of each year is (to take into account the # of quarters of data per year?)

Comment: Perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26294883/adding-more-x-axix-labels-in-ggplot/26295796#26295796 will help.