# How to create multiple mixed legends in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following plot in `ggplot2` (made-up modification of the ChickWeight dataframe):

```
require(ggplot2) 
ChickWt <- data.frame(ChickWeight, Sex = rep(c("M", "F"), times = 289))  
p1 <- ggplot(ChickWt, aes(x=Time, y=weight,
colour=Diet, Group = Chick, linetype = Sex)) + geom_line()
p1
```

which yields the following:

[image]

This is fine, except for the legend.

I would like the legend to be of four pairs:

Diet 1-M (colored Purple, solid line), 
Diet 1-F (colored Purple, brokem line),

Diet 2-M (colored Green, solid line), 
Diet 2-F (colored Green, brokem line), 
....

and so on. Let us say I would like to put the labels in a 2x2 block. 
I believe that I can put the labels in a 2x2 block using

```
p1 + guides(fill=guide_legend(nrow = 2, ncol = 2))
```

but the question I am stumped on is how to make the legend for the four pairs of diet-gender combinations. Any suggestions would be a great help!

Answer (score 1):

You can get a single legend by using the `interaction` function to generate all the combinations of `Diet` and `Sex` and then manually setting the colors and linetypes to the values you desire for each Diet-Sex combination.

```
require(ggplot2)
require(dplyr)

# Add Sex column
set.seed(104)
ChickWt = ChickWeight %>% group_by(Chick) %>%
  mutate(Sex = sample(c("M","F"),1))

plot.colors = hcl(seq(15,375,length.out=5)[1:4],100,65)

ggplot(ChickWt, aes(x=Time, y=weight, 
                          colour=interaction(Diet,Sex,sep="-"), 
                          linetype = interaction(Diet,Sex,sep="-"), 
                          group=Chick)) + 
  geom_line() +
  scale_colour_manual(values=plot.colors[rep(1:4, 2)], name="Diet-Sex") +
  scale_linetype_manual(values=rep(1:2, each=4), name="Diet-Sex") +
  guides(colour=guide_legend(ncol=2))
```

[image]

Comment: But there appears to be no 1-F, 3-M, 4-M. Also, how do I get in four separate pairs, for each diet? Thanks!

Comment: The combinations of Diet and Sex that appear in the graph are only those that appear in the data. 1-F, 3-M, and 4-M don't appear in the data and so are absent from the graph. You can see the combinations that occur in the data by doing, for example, `with(ChickWt, unique(paste(Diet,Sex,sep="-")))`, which gives `"1-M" "2-M" "2-F" "3-F" "4-F"`.

Comment: sorry, edited to have 8 combinations in the example now. I still want it in four pairs of Diets (with linetype representing sex).

Comment: See updated code. I created the `Sex` column so as to keep `Sex` constant for each value of `Chick` and to also ensure that every combination of `Diet` and `Sex` is present in the data.

Comment: Thank you! I am almost there. What if I wanted to have two headings: "Male Diets" and "Female Diets" for the two columns? Also, can I put a box around each of the legends (and put them inside the plot, this i know how to do)? Perhaps, it would be better to switch color and linetype in the above graph -- with color for gender and linetype for Diet for two columns.

Comment: Two separate legend titles and putting separate borders around the male and female legends will require (as far as I know) lower-level grid functions to directly manipulate the legend grobs. Probably best to ask a separate question on that. [This SO answer might help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27803710/ggplot2-divide-legend-into-two-columns-each-with-its-own-title/27804153#27804153), though it's not a complete solution.

Comment: Thanks! Btw, how does one draw a box around the legend?