# r ggplot2: grouping legend in bar plots

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, legend

I try to visualize two discrete variables in barplot with ggplot2 using `fill` and `alpha` for them respectively. The standard way to do so is as follows:

```
#creating data and building the basic bar plot
library(ggplot2)
myleg<-read.csv(text="lett,num
a,1
a,2
b,1
b,2
h,1
h,2
h,3
h,4")
ggplot(myleg, aes(lett, alpha = factor(num), fill = lett)) +
  geom_bar(position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE)) +
  scale_alpha_discrete(range = c(1, .1),
                       name = "alpha legend",
                       labels = c("alpha lab 4","alpha lab 3",
                                  "alpha lab 2", "alpha lab 1")) +
  labs(title = "initial bar plot for data")
```

[image: initial bar plot of data]

The default legend is grouped according to two different ways of presentation (coloring for lett and grey scale, or opacity for num).

I need to have the legend grouped as data bars on the plot. i.e. three color strips, each with changing alpha levels. The partial solution is to generate the plots with desired three legend strips separately as follows:

```
ggplot(myleg,aes(lett,alpha=factor(num),fill=lett)) +geom_bar(position="stack",fill="#f8766d") +scale_alpha_discrete(name="red legend",labels=c("red lab 2","red lab 1"),breaks=c("3","4"))
ggplot(myleg,aes(lett,alpha=factor(num),fill=lett)) +geom_bar(position="stack",fill="#00ba38") +scale_alpha_discrete(name="green legend",labels=c("green lab 2","green lab 1"),breaks=c("3","4"))
ggplot(myleg,aes(lett,alpha=factor(num),fill=lett)) +geom_bar(position="stack",fill="#619cff") +scale_alpha_discrete(name="blue legend",labels=c("blue lab 4","blue lab 3","blue lab 2", "blue lab 1"))
```

The output is:
[image: artificially created plots with needed legend strips]

So for now I can only cut and paste three legend strips onto the main graph, for example, in inkscape, to produce the desired result:

[image: final plot with desired legend]

How it is possible to program this in a decent way?

Comment: Marco's answer below is the "right" way to do it, but for particularly fiddly figures, at some point your way of doing it in Inkscape is the better and more customizable way.

Comment: I edited my answer suggesting the solution for the new problem posted by @astrsk

Comment: Since I found this thread first but found a more easily adaptable answer here I'm leaving a link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27803710/ggplot2-divide-legend-into-two-columns-each-with-its-own-title

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can draw a customized legend  using `scale_fill_manual`:

```
df <- mtcars
df$cyl <- factor(df$cyl)
df$vs <- factor(df$vs)

library(ggplot2)    
p <- ggplot(df,aes(x=cyl, fill=interaction(cyl,vs))) + geom_bar(position="stack") 

# Breaks
brks <- levels(interaction(df$cyl,df$vs))

# Values - Colors
library(scales)
pal <- hue_pal()(3)
cls <- as.character(c(sapply(pal,alpha,0.3),sapply(pal,alpha,1)))

# Labels
lbls <- paste(levels(df$cyl), "-", rep(levels(df$vs),each=3))

p  + scale_fill_manual(name ='Cyl - Vs', breaks=brks, values=cls, labels=lbls)
```

[image]

**EDIT** Here is a solution for the (new) problem posted by @astrsk (after his/her change of the initial question).

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)
myleg <- structure(list(lett = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L,
3L), .Label = c("a", "b", "h"), class = "factor"), num = c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L)), .Names = c("lett", "num"), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))

getLegend <- function(p) {
   g <- ggplotGrob(p)
   k <- which(g$layout$name=="guide-box")
   g$grobs[[k]]
}

p1 <- ggplot(myleg,aes(lett,alpha=factor(num),fill=lett)) +geom_bar(position="stack",fill="#f8766d") +scale_alpha_discrete(name="red legend",labels=c("red lab 2","red lab 1"),breaks=c("3","4"))
p2 <- ggplot(myleg,aes(lett,alpha=factor(num),fill=lett)) +geom_bar(position="stack",fill="#00ba38") +scale_alpha_discrete(name="green legend",labels=c("green lab 2","green lab 1"),breaks=c("3","4"))
p3 <- ggplot(myleg,aes(lett,alpha=factor(num),fill=lett)) +geom_bar(position="stack",fill="#619cff") +scale_alpha_discrete(name="blue legend",labels=c("blue lab 4","blue lab 3","blue lab 2", "blue lab 1"))

p <- ggplot(myleg,aes(lett,alpha=factor(num),fill=lett)) +
     geom_bar(position=position_stack(reverse=T)) +
     scale_alpha_discrete(range=c(1,.1), name="alpha legend",
       labels=c("alpha lab 4","alpha lab 3","alpha lab 2", "alpha lab 1")) +
     labs(title="initial bar plot for data")
g <- ggplotGrob(p)

k <- which(g$layout$name=="guide-box")
g$grobs[[k]] <- grid.arrange(getLegend(p1),getLegend(p2),getLegend(p3),ncol=1)
grid.draw(g)
```

[image]

Comment: I would still say both your answers are the "right" way to do it :) Pulling out the legend from the gtables is pretty slick though!