# Several arbitrary legends in ggplot (histogram)

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I'm trying to make a single plot out of the next two:

```
datos <- rnorm(100000)
datos <- data.frame(boot=datos)
ggplot(datos, aes(x=boot)) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..),
                 colour="white",
                 fill="steelblue")+
  geom_density(alpha=.2, fill="gold",col="gold",lwd=0.75) +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = mean(datos$boot),color="Media"),
             lwd=0.75)+
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = quantile(datos$boot,0.95)),
             lwd=0.75,linetype="dashed")+
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0,col="black",lwd=1)+
  scale_color_manual(name = "Estadísticas",
                     values = c(Media = "red"))+
  labs(title=latex2exp::TeX("Figura 1: Histograma De las $R^2_{adj}$ obtenidas por \\textit{bootstrap}"),
       subtitle="Experimento realizado con 10,000 muestras independientes",
       y="Densidad estimada", x=latex2exp::TeX("$R^2_{adj}$"))
```

[image]

And

```
datos <- rnorm(100000)
datos <- data.frame(boot=datos)
ggplot(datos, aes(x=boot)) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..),
                 colour="white",
                 fill="steelblue")+
  geom_density(alpha=.2, fill="gold",col="gold",lwd=0.75) +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = mean(datos$boot)),
             lwd=0.75)+
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = quantile(datos$boot,0.95),color="Normal"),
             lwd=0.75,linetype="dashed")+
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0,col="black",lwd=1)+
  scale_color_manual(name = "Intervalos",
                     values = c(Normal = "green"))+
  labs(title=latex2exp::TeX("Figura 1: Histograma De las $R^2_{adj}$ obtenidas por \\textit{bootstrap}"),
       subtitle="Experimento realizado con 10,000 muestras independientes",
       y="Densidad estimada", x=latex2exp::TeX("$R^2_{adj}$"))
```

[image]

What I want to do is a single plot in which I have two groups of line legends "Intervalos" and "Estadísticas". This is what I need:

[image]

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10349206/add-legend-to-ggplot2-line-plot

Comment: I've made it simpler now

Comment: Not really MrFlick... I need two groups of plot

Comment: Then maybe something like this instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46683956/create-two-legends-for-one-ggplot2-graph-and-modify-them. ggplot doesn't like two make two legends for the same aesthetic so you're going to have to do some hacking.

Comment: Or another guide here: https://www.r-bloggers.com/2015/11/multiple-legends-for-the-same-aesthetic-2/

Comment: None of this work for me, since I want to add lines to a histogram MrFlick, not just lines...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

1. Transform the data inside the `geom_vline()` function to obtain a tidy dataset with the mean and the 0.95 quartile.
2. Map the `geom_vline()` aesthetics to the 2x2 dataset from step 1.
3. Edit the linetype and colour scales to add a line with the metric string (¿"Medida", "Medición"?), and another one with its name (media, normal). Unfortunately, IMHO, this looks ugly.

   ```
    ggplot(datos, aes(x=boot)) + 
    geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..),
                   colour="white",
                   fill="steelblue")+
    geom_density(alpha=.2, fill="gold",col="gold",lwd=0.75) +
    geom_vline(data = (. %>% summarise(media = mean(boot), 
                                      normal = quantile(boot, 0.95)) %>% 
                             gather(key = Medida, value = valor)),
             aes(xintercept = valor, color = Medida, linetype = Medida),
             lwd=0.75) +
     geom_hline(yintercept = 0,col="black",lwd=1) +
     scale_color_manual(name = "Medida",
                     values = c("media" = "red", "normal" = "green"),
                     labels = c("ESTADÍSTICAS\nmedia", "INTERVALOS\nnormal" )) +
     scale_linetype_manual(name = "Medida",
                        values = c("media" = 1, "normal" = 2),
                        labels = c("ESTADÍSTICAS\nmedia", "INTERVALOS\nnormal" )) +
    labs(title=latex2exp::TeX("Figura 1: Histograma De las $R^2_{adj}$ obtenidas por \\textit{bootstrap}"),
         subtitle="Experimento realizado con 10,000 muestras independientes",
         y="Densidad estimada", 
         x=latex2exp::TeX("$R^2_{adj}$"))
   ```

[image]