# How to add multiple titles in legend ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

How to add multiple titles  in legend  ggplot?

```
library(RColorBrewer)
library(ggplot2)
data1<-data.frame(x= rnorm(20, 0,1), 
                  y=rnorm(20, 1,1), 
                  section=c("a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5", "a6", "a7", 
                        "a8",  "a9","a10","b1", "b2", "c1",   "c2", "c3", 
                         "d1", "d2", "e1", "e2","f1"),
                  region=c(rep("a",10), rep("b",2),rep("c",3),rep("d",2), 
                             rep("e",2), rep("f",1))) #data

newpalette<-c(colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(9,"Blues"))(15)[15:6], 
            brewer.pal(9,"Greens")[c(4,8)], 
          brewer.pal(9,"Oranges")[c(4,7,9)], 
          brewer.pal(9,"Purples")[c(4,8)],      
          brewer.pal(9,"BrBG")[c(1,3)], 
          brewer.pal(9,"Greys")[5]) #20 color values
labels<-c("a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5", "a6", "a7", "a8", "a9","a10",
          "b1", "b2", 
           "c1",   "c2", "c3",
           "d1", "d2", 
           "e1", "e2",
           "f1")
 data1$section<-factor(data1$section,levels= labels)     
 p.legend<-ggplot( ) + 
           geom_point(data=data1, aes(x, y, colour = section, 
           shape=section), size=2)+
           scale_color_manual(values =newpalette ,labels= labels)+
           scale_shape_manual(values = 
           c(rep(1,10),0,0,2,2,2,3,3,5,5,6),labels= labels)
```

I want the region values as the subtitles in legend like following figure.

[image]

Mayebe we could modify spacing of **some specific** legend keys (e.g. legend key a10, c3). And then use `grid.text` adding the text (a, b, c...) into the spacing like [How to add multiple legend titles (columns) in ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51363173/how-to-add-multiple-legend-titles-columns-in-ggplot). But my subtitiles are more complex and I don't know how to modify spacing of some specific legend keys.

Or we could create some another values (e.g. a11) and make it lucency in legend. Then adding the text b into the a11 spacing.But I don't know how to remove the specific legend keys and texts.

The third ways, I had ever add `\n\n` into some labels codes to create the spacing.

```
labels2<- c("a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5", "a6", "a7", "a8", "a9","a10\n\n",
          "b1", "b2", 
           "c1",   "c2", "c3\n\n",
           "d1", "d2\n\n", 
           "e1", "e2\n\n",
           "f1")
p.legend<-ggplot( ) + 
           geom_point(data=data1, aes(x, y, colour = section, 
           shape=section), size=2)+
           scale_color_manual(values =newpalette ,labels= labels2)+
           scale_shape_manual(values = 
           c(rep(1,10),0,0,2,2,2,3,3,5,5,6),labels= labels2)
```

But the labels and key would not align like following figure

[image]

These are three ways that I had tried and failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using @Mark Peterson's suggestion ([ggplot2: Divide Legend into Two Columns, Each with Its Own Title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27803710/ggplot2-divide-legend-into-two-columns-each-with-its-own-title)) to use `cowplot`, here is one way:

```
library(cowplot)

# create chart without legend
p <- ggplot( ) + 
  geom_point(data=data1, aes(x, y, colour = section, shape = section), size = 2) +
  scale_color_manual(values = newpalette) + scale_shape_manual(values = c(rep(1,10),0,0,2,2,2,3,3,5,5,6)) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")

# To create individaul ggplot for each region
region_i <- unique(data1$region)

for (i in 1:length(region_i)) {

  region_d <- data1[data1$region == region_i[i], ]

  # this is to keep same shapes as above
  shape_ind <- switch(i, 
                      "1" = "1", 
                      "2" = "0",
                      "3" = "2", 
                      "4" = "3",
                      "5" = "5", 
                      "6" = "6")

  # ggplots to be saved in p1, p2 etc...
  nam <- paste0("p", i)

  # ggplots for each region with different colours and shapes for these regions
  my_plot <- ggplot() + 
    geom_point(data = region_d, aes(x, y, colour = section, shape = section), size=2) +
    scale_color_manual(values = newpalette[which(data1$region == region_i[i])]) +
    scale_shape_manual(values = c(rep(as.numeric(shape_ind), nrow(region_d)))) + 
    labs(color = unique(region_d$region), shape = unique(region_d$region))

  # call p1, p2 etc.. to see the plots
  assign(nam, my_plot)

}

# cowplot to combine the plots
plot_grid(p, 
          plot_grid(get_legend(p1), get_legend(p2), ncol = 1), # a and b to be kept in one column
          plot_grid(get_legend(p3), get_legend(p4), get_legend(p5), get_legend(p6), ncol = 1),  # c, d, e and f in one column
          ncol = 3, rel_widths = c(4, 1, 1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it does work. However when I use "for" , it will get error.  The plot p1-p6 can not be drawn. The error for p1 is following. Error: Insufficient values in manual scale. 10 needed but only 1 provided. If I draw the p1-p6 one by one without "for" code, It will work. I don't know why. Thank you very much.

Comment: That's strange. Can you check `scale_color_manual` and `scale_shape_manual`? For `i = 1`, you need to make sure there are 10 values in manual scale. Hence why there is the line `newpalette[which(data1$region == region_i[i])]` and `c(rep(as.numeric(shape_ind), nrow(region_d))`

Comment: I had checked scale_color_manual and scale_shape_manual. There is no problem with the  manual scale when  i=1 (or 2-6), and the plot p1 can also be drawn. The error would come out only when I used the "for" code. Anyway, thanks a lot.