# Fit linetype in the legend of a multifactorial plot, using ggplot and pipes

Tags: r

The following code is used to plot a number of different conditions using a combination of colours and linetypes. It plots "R" using a line and "W" using a dashed line.

I'd like to split the legend into two parts: *Condition* for "H C" and "I C", and *Model type* for "R" and  "W". In *Condition*, we want to represent lines' color. In *Model type*, we want to represent lines' type (e.g. dashed and non dashed lines in black).

Since I am using pipes, I have not found a solution for this so far.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
tribble(    ~y,    ~cb,   ~z,    ~x,
            1     , 0,   "H C R"    ,1,
            2     , 1,   "H C R"    ,1,
            2     , 0,   "I C R"    ,1,
            3     , 1,   "I C R"    ,1,
            1.5   , 0,   "H C W"    ,1,
            2     , 1,   "H C W"    ,1,
            2     , 0,   "I C W"    ,1,
            2     , 1,   "I C W"    ,1,
            3     , 0,   "H C R"    ,2,
            3     , 1,   "H C R"    ,2,
            0.5   , 0,   "I C R"    ,2,
            2     , 1,   "I C R"    ,2,
            2     , 0,   "H C W"    ,2,
            2     , 1,   "H C W"    ,2,
            1     , 0,   "I C W"    ,2,
            1     , 1,   "I C W"    ,2)-> datos


aux<-datos %>%
  group_by(x, z, cb) %>%
  summarise(media = mean(y), 
            desvio = rnorm(1),
            error_est = desvio / sqrt(n()),             
            intervalo_sup = media + (2*error_est),       
            intervalo_inf = media - (2*error_est)) #%>%


library(RColorBrewer)
display.brewer.pal(11,name = "Spectral")  
brewer.pal(n = 11, name = "Spectral")
# Que la línea de condición "H C" apareciera en el color anaranjado que utiliza la paleta "Spectral".
# Que la línea de condición "I C" apareciera en el color verde oscuro que utiliza la paleta "Spectral".
colores<-brewer.pal(n = 11, name = "Spectral")[c(3,3,9,9)]




  ggplot() +

  geom_line(data=aux%>%filter(grepl("W",z)),
            aes(x = x, y = media, color = z,group = z),
            size=0.5,
            linetype = "dashed") +                      
  geom_errorbar(data=aux%>%filter(grepl("W",z)),aes(x = x, color = z,
                              ymax = intervalo_sup,               
                    ymin = intervalo_inf),
                width=0.3) + 

    geom_line(data=aux%>%filter(!grepl("W",z)),
              aes(x = x, y = media, color = z,group = z),
              size=0.5) +                      
    geom_errorbar(data=aux%>%filter(!grepl("W",z)),
                  aes(x = x, color = z,
                                ymax = intervalo_sup,               
                                ymin = intervalo_inf),
                  width=0.3)+
  labs(x = "x", y = "y", color = "Condition") +

  scale_color_manual(values=colores) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1,7, by=1)) +
  theme(legend.position="bottom", legend.text=element_text(size=12)) +
  guides(color=guide_legend(ncol=2)) +
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=14),
        axis.title=element_text(size=14))+
  facet_wrap(~cb)
```

[image]

Comment: You may want to have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27803710/ggplot2-divide-legend-into-two-columns-each-with-its-own-title

Comment: @aaumai thanks for this. You're right that question is useful to divide the legend into two groups. However, I attempt to divide also the labels of each level in the legend.

Answer (score 0):

Solution using `stringr`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(stringr)

#Selection of desired colors
display.brewer.pal(11,name = "Spectral") 
colores<-brewer.pal(n = 11, name = "Spectral")[c(3,9)]

#Stats
datos %>%
  group_by(x, z, cb) %>%
  summarise(media = mean(y), 
            desvio = rnorm(1),                         
            error_est = desvio / sqrt(n()),             
            intervalo_sup = media + (2*error_est),       
            intervalo_inf = media - (2*error_est))%>%
  #Two columns for color and linetype (be careful when using stringr)
  mutate(Model=str_split(z," ")[[1]][3],
         Condition=str_remove(z,Model)
            )%>%
  #Plot
ggplot(aes(x = x, y = media, color = Condition,group = z)) +
  geom_line(aes(linetype=Model, color=Condition),size=0.5)+
  geom_errorbar(aes(x = x, color = Condition,
                    ymax = intervalo_sup,               
                    ymin = intervalo_inf),
                width=0.3)+
  scale_color_manual(values=colores) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1,7, by=1)) +
  theme(legend.position="bottom", legend.text=element_text(size=12)) +
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=14),
        axis.title=element_text(size=14))+
  facet_wrap(~cb)+
  # Legends' title
  guides(color=guide_legend("Condition"),
         linetype=guide_legend("Model"))
```