# How to better differentiate lines in ggplot for the visually impaired?

Tags: r, ggplot2

In running the below code, I'm trying to better delineate and visualize the plot lines in order to help the visually impaired (like me, colour blind and blind spots in my visual field). Even the dashed lines as currently presented look too much alike and I can hardly tell them apart. How can one add markers, and other distinguishing features as illustrated below, so this is easier to read?

[image]

Code:

```
library(feasts)
library(fable)
library(ggplot2)
library(tsibble)

tmp <- data.frame(
  Month = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
  StateX = c(1527,1297,933,832,701,488,424,353,302,280)
  ) %>%
  as_tsibble(index = Month)
tmpNext4 <- data.frame(
  Month = c(11,12,13,14),
  StateX = c(211,182,153,125)
  ) %>%
  as_tsibble(index = Month)

# Fit the models to tmp dataframe:
fit <- tmp %>%
  model(
    Mean = MEAN(StateX),
    `Naïve` = NAIVE(StateX),
    Drift = NAIVE(StateX ~ drift())
  )

# Produce forecasts for the next 4 months:
fcTmp <- fit %>%
  forecast(new_data = tmpNext4)

# Plot the forecasts:
fcTmp %>%
  ggplot(aes(Month, .mean)) +
  geom_line(aes(linetype = .model, color = .model)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = StateX, linetype = "Actual", color = "Actual"), data = tmpNext4) +
  geom_line(aes(y = StateX), data = tmp)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ggplot2: Divide Legend into Two Columns, Each with Its Own Title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27803710/ggplot2-divide-legend-into-two-columns-each-with-its-own-title)

Comment: I'm digging through that post to see how it applies to my situation

Comment: The simplest thing would be to use the `size` parameter for your line layers to make them as thick as you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The harder part is split the legend in two, we can use `ggnewscale::new_scale_color()` to create a new layer for our `geom_line` with the actual data. You can find others way of doing this in this [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27803710/ggplot2-divide-legend-into-two-columns-each-with-its-own-title).

- To make the different points we use `geom_point(aes(shape = .model, color = .model))`
- To make the line thicker we use `geom_line(..., linewidth = 1.2)`
- `scales::hue_pal()` is used so we can mantain ggplot2 original colors

```r
# Produce forecasts for the next 4 months:
fcTmp <- fit %>%
  forecast(new_data = tmpNext4)

legend_title = "Forecast"
# Plot the forecasts:
fcTmp %>%
  ggplot(aes(Month, .mean)) +
  geom_line(aes(linetype = .model, color = .model)) +
  geom_point(aes(shape = .model, color = .model)) + 
  scale_color_manual(aesthetics = "colour",values = scales::hue_pal()(4)[-1]) + 
  labs(linetype =legend_title ,shape = legend_title, colour = legend_title) +
  ggnewscale::new_scale_color() +
  geom_line(aes(y = StateX, color = "Actual"), data = tmpNext4,  linewidth = 1.2) +
  geom_line(aes(y = StateX), data = tmp, linewidth = 1.2)  +
  scale_color_manual(aesthetics = "colour",values = scales::hue_pal()(1), name = "")

Created on 2023-01-24 with reprex v2.0.2
```

[image]

Comment: Your explanation is very helpful.  ggplot seems quite complicated!