# Transparency in X and Y labels - ggplot2, R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to make the X and Y labels transparent in a certain degree. However, (1) I can't find something that works in the `scale_x_continuous()` function as it doesn't have the `alpha` function available. Is there any another way (without `alpha`) to make them transparent in a certain degree?

This is the code:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=X, y=Y)) + 
    geom_point(colour="red",size=3) +
  geom_text_repel(label=df$Label, family="sans", fontface="bold", size=3) + 
  scale_x_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format(accuracy = 1), limits = c(0, 0.5)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format(accuracy = 1), limits = c(0, 1),position = "right") +
  annotate("rect", xmin = 0.25, xmax = Inf, ymin = 0.5, ymax = -Inf, fill= "brown2", alpha=0.3) +
  theme_light() +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0.5,alpha=0.3, color="blue") + geom_vline(xintercept = 0.25,alpha=0.3,color="blue")
```

Comment: Do you really need them to be transparent, or just lighter, to match the aesthetic of the rest of your plot?

Comment: Both of them. Because it doesn't has to match with just the aesthetic of the plot, but also with the whole format of the power point presentation. In some of them I need it transparent, on other just lighter (that's why I'm traying to find an "alpha").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it isn't pretty, but here's one way to get what you're looking for, based largely on [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31079210/how-can-i-add-annotations-below-the-x-axis-in-ggplot2/53531754#53531754) to annotating outside of the plot boundaries.

There isn't an alpha argument in `scale_x_continuous()` for the label, nor is there one is `element_text()` in the theme argument. You *can* specify alpha for text made with `annotate()` and you can place these annotations outside the plot area, so this solution uses that approach.

```
df <- data.frame(X=runif(1), Y=rnorm(1))
ggplot(df, aes(x=X, y=Y)) + 
  geom_point(colour="red",size=3) +
  # geom_text_repel(label=df$Label, family="sans", fontface="bold", size=3) +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format(accuracy = 1)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format(accuracy = 1), position = "right") +
  annotate("rect", xmin = 0.25, xmax = Inf, ymin = 0.5, ymax = -Inf, fill= "brown2", alpha=0.3) +
  theme_light() +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0.5,alpha=0.3, color="blue") + geom_vline(xintercept = 0.25,alpha=0.3,color="blue") +
  theme(axis.title=element_blank(),
     plot.margin = unit(c(5,10,10,5), "mm")) +
  annotate("text", label="X", x=0.25, y=-0.15, alpha=0.5) +
  annotate("text", label="Y", x=0.58, y=0.5, alpha=0.5) +
  coord_cartesian(clip="off", ylim=c(0,1), xlim=c(0,0.5))
```

A couple notes:

- You need to use `coord_cartesian()` and specify `clip="off"` to allow annotations outside the plot area. To keep the plot focused on the right area, you also need to specify `xlim` and `ylim`, which means you can't specify those parameters in `scale_x/y_continuous()`. (I've removed these from your original code.)
- You also need to specify plot margins that leave you enough space for the label. It takes some trial and error to figure out what these could/should be.
- It also takes a some work to figure out where the transparent axis labels should be, so this isn't a great approach if you have more than a few plots.

[image]