# ggplot function to add text just below legend

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

In R I want to make a function which takes an ggplot object and some text  and returns and ggplot object by adds text just below the legend (in the right side of the plot, while keeping legend on the right side).

```
myplot = ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width, color=Species)) + 
           geom_line()
```

I want to add text "mean of Sepal.Width = 3.05" (and a box around it) just after the legend. I looked at related questions but they change the position of legend to bottom and do not work as a function rather prints the plot.

Comment: this post might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12409960/ggplot2-annotate-outside-of-plot

Comment: Thanks. This is helpful but the problem is now how to find the xmin and ymin values ??

Comment: take `max()` of the original mapped `x` value and add some small percentage to it

Comment: See [cowplot package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cowplot/vignettes/introduction.html)

Comment: @zx8754  cowplot seems promising but still my problem is how to get the position of legend so that text can be added bellow that!!

Comment: @hrbrmstr For x value max(x)+small percent is good idea but for y value it overlaps on the top of legend!! It will be easy if somehow I can get legend position co-ordinates

Comment: You need to play with `vjust` and `hjust` to get it to add text below legend. `draw_label("Plot is underneath the grey boxes", x = 1, y = 1,vjust = 1, hjust = 1)`

Answer (score 8):

A couple of possibilities.

The first uses `annotate()`, and involves positioning the text by trial and error.  The x position is adjusted using `hjust`, the y position is selected to be a little below the legend. Note: no border around the text.

The second assumes a border is required. The combined text and box is constructed using `grid`. Then the grob is positioned using `annotation_custom()`. `ymin` and `ymax` are set to be a little below the legend. `xmin` and `xmax` are set by trial and error to get the text and the legend to align.

Both methods involve plotting outside the plot panel, so clipping to the plot panel needs to be turned off. But if the text size or length changes, the position of the label needs to be adjusted.

The third method is reasonably robust to changes to text length and size. Similar to method 2, the combined text and box grob is constructed using `grid`. Then, using `gtable` functions, the grob is attached to the legend (to the middle column of the legend).

```
# 1.
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
library(gtable)

# The label
label = "Mean of Sepal.Width = 3.05"

# The plot - Note the extra margin space for the label
myplot = ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width, color=Species)) + 
    geom_line() +   
    annotate("text", x = Inf, y = 2.9, label = label, hjust = -0.08, size = 3) +
    theme(plot.margin = unit(c(.5,6,.5,.5),"lines"),
          legend.background = element_rect(colour = "black"))

# Turn off clipping to the plot panel
g = ggplotGrob(myplot)
g$layout$clip[g$layout$name == "panel"] = "off"
grid.draw(g)


# 2.
# Construct the label grob - a combination of text and box
textgrob = textGrob(label, gp = gpar(cex = .75), )
width = unit(1, "grobwidth",textgrob) + unit(10, "points")
height = unit(1, "grobheight", textgrob)+ unit(10, "points")
rectgrob = rectGrob(gp=gpar(colour = "black", fill = NA), height = height, width = width)
labelGrob = gTree("labelGrob", children = gList(rectgrob, textgrob))

# The plot - Note the extra margin space for the label
myplot = ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width, color=Species)) + 
    geom_line() +   
    annotation_custom(labelGrob,  
       xmin = 1.137*max(iris$Sepal.Length), xmax = 1.137*max(iris$Sepal.Length), 
       ymin = 2.9, ymax = 2.9) +
    theme(plot.margin = unit(c(0.5, 6, 0.5, 0.5), "lines"),
          legend.background = element_rect(colour = "black"))

# Turn off clipping to the plot panel
g = ggplotGrob(myplot)
g$layout$clip[g$layout$name == "panel"] = "off"
grid.draw(g)




#3.
# The label
label = "Mean of\nSepal.Width = 3.05"
# Try a different label
# label = "a"

# The plot
myplot = ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width, color=Species)) + 
    geom_line() +   
    theme(legend.background = element_rect(colour = "black"))

# Get the legend
g = ggplotGrob(myplot)
leg = g$grobs[[which(g$layout$name == "guide-box")]]

# Construct the label grob 
xpos = 5
textgrob = textGrob(x = unit(xpos, "points"), label, gp = gpar(cex = .75), just = "left")
width = unit(1, "grobwidth",textgrob) + unit(2*xpos, "points")  # twice the x position
height = unit(1, "grobheight", textgrob)+ unit(2*xpos, "points")
rectgrob = rectGrob(x = unit(0, "points"), just = "left", 
    gp = gpar(colour = "black", fill = NA), height = height, width = width)
labelGrob = gTree("labelGrob", children = gList(rectgrob, textgrob))

# Add the label grob to a new row added to the legend
pos = subset(leg$layout, grepl("guides", name), t:r)

leg = gtable_add_rows(leg, height, pos = pos$t+1)
leg = gtable_add_grob(leg, labelGrob, t = pos$t+2, l = pos$l)

# Adjust the middle width of the legend to be the maximum of the original width 
# or the width of the grob
leg$widths[pos$l] = max(width, leg$widths[pos$l])

# Add some space between the two parts of the legend
leg$heights[pos$t+1] = unit(5, "pt")

# Return the modified legend to the origial plot
g$grobs[[which(g$layout$name == "guide-box")]] = leg

# Adjust the width of the column containing the legend to be the maximum 
# of the original width or the width of the label
g$widths[g$layout[grepl("guide-box", g$layout$name), "l"]] = max(width, sum(leg$widths))

# Draw the plot
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(g)
```

[image]

Comment: Very thorough, thanks. Where can one learn more about lower level aspects of grobs, etc. ?

Comment: Is it possible to center the label text relative to the original legend? When I try, it centers overall.

Comment: This may work, but it is quite complicated. It shouldn't be this difficult

Comment: Updates for method #1 (which I prefer): 
A) You can now disable clipping with `coord_cartesian(clip="off")`.
B) Fine-tune label position with `nudge_x` or `nudge_y`.
C) For more complicated uses (e.g., multiple labels), consider replacing `annotate()` with `geom_text(data=data.frame(lab='text'), aes=aes(label=lab), inherit.aes=F, y=2.9, size=3, ...)`

Answer (score 3):

Another easy possibility is to use a caption:

```r
myplot = ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width, color=Species)) + 
           geom_line() +
           labs(caption = "Mean of Sepal.Width = 3.05")
```

It's not really right below the legend, though:

[image: Output]