# ggplot2: Remove minor ticks on x axis but keep major ticks

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis, label

I'm starting with the following R code for ggplot2 (taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/39724176 with minor modifications):

```
lims = c(0,100)

breaks.major <- c(0,15,37.5,52.5,67.5,82.5,95) #defines the midpoints of the categories (label locations)
breaks.minor <- c(30,45,60,75,90,100)   #defines the edges of the categories (second label set I need)

breaks.comb <- sort(c(breaks.major2, breaks.minor2 - 1.0E-6))  # avoid the just same value as minor
label.comb <- c(0, "\nExtremely \nDissatisfied", 30, "\nDissatisfied", 45, "\nUncertain", 60, 
                "\nSatisfied", 75, "\nVery \nSatisfied", 90, "\nExtremely \nSatisfied", 100)

library(ggplot2)
g <- ggplot(mpg, aes(class))+
  geom_bar()+
  coord_flip()+
  scale_y_continuous(limit = lims, minor_breaks = breaks.minor, breaks = breaks.comb, 
                     labels = label.comb, expand = c(0,0)) +
  theme(panel.grid.major.x = element_blank()) +
  theme(panel.grid.major.y = element_blank()) +
  #theme(axis.ticks.x=element_blank()) + #Hides ALL ticks!
  theme(axis.title= element_blank()) +
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5), "lines"))
g
```

I would like to hide (some of) the ticks on the x axis. I'm aware, that this can be done by using:

```
theme(axis.ticks.x=element_blank())
```

but I would like to hide only the minor ticks (as specified in "minor_breaks"), but not the major ticks. Is there a way to only hide the minor ticks and/or specify which minor/major ticks are to be shown and which not?

Comment: I'm confused, doesn't [cuttlefish's answer at the question you link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39724176/903061) do exactly what you want?

Comment: Oh, I see - cuttlefish's answer gets rid of all the tick marks.  `ggplot` doesn't distinguish between major and minor tick marks (minor breaks don't get tick marks, which is why your code uses `breaks = breaks.comb`, not `breaks = breaks.major`). I think to get the tick marks and the extra labels you'll have to do something like hrbrmstr's answer which should work fine if you omit the `axis.ticks.x=element_blank()` line.

Comment: @Gregor thank you for the quick answer!
Hmmm, I tried @hrbrmstr's answer, but
1) I don't manage to reproduce his figure with his code (the values of the second axis are not shown) - Can you confirm this?
2) When I omit:
a) `gg1 <- gg1 + theme(axis.ticks.x=element_blank())` the "minor ticks" (i. e. the ticks for the category labels) are shown, but not the "major ones" (i. e., the ones for the values)
b) `gg2 <- gg2 + theme(axis.ticks.x=element_blank())` all ticks are missing

Comment: Furthermore, I was hoping I could use @cuttlefish's answer, as it has less dependencies (my actual figure is way more complex and relies on a package that is derived from ggplot2). If, however, this is the only solution (given that issue 1 and 2 can be solved), I will try to implement hrbrmstr's answer for my setting.

Thank you for your help!