# Add additional x-axis labels to a ggplot2 plot (with discrete axis labels) using cowplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, cowplot

I am trying to add additional x-axis labels to a ggplot2 plot with discrete axis labels. I have tried a few approaches (including some that use `grid`, i.e. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39717545/add-secondary-x-axis-labels-to-ggplot-with-one-x-axis)), but have settled on using the `add_sub()` function from the `cowplot` package. However, it does not seem straightforward to add more than one addition label, as subsequent labels add *below the plot already-modified with one additional label, whereas it should be vertically aligned with it*). Here is an example, where "My Label" is in the correct position, but "My Second Label" is not. I've tried manually adjusting the vertical / y-axis position of the second label, but the same problem emerges with subsequent labels (in fact in a more tricky form, as the same adjustment that worked for the second label does not work in any straightforward way for the third). Here is an example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'cowplot'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:ggplot2':
#> 
#>     ggsave

p <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = carat, y = price, color = cut)) +
    geom_point()

p1 <- add_sub(p, label = "My Label", x = .125)
p2 <- add_sub(p1, label = "My Second Label", x = .275)

ggdraw(p2)
```

[image]

How can I add additional x-axis labels to a `ggplot2` plot (with discrete axis labels) using the `add_sub()` function from `cowplot`?

Answer (score 1):

You get this result because `add_sub` is taking the input plot and writing below it, thus everytime you add another `add_sub` you'll be 1 level lower.

This is what I'd do to work around it:

```
p <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = carat, y = price, color = cut)) +
  geom_point()

p1 <- add_sub(p, label = c("My Label   My Second Label"))

ggdraw(p1)
```

[image]

and of course you can add more spaces between or make other tweaks as needed.

Comment: This is great - but is surprisingly hard to use to get the labels in just the right position.

Comment: @JoshuaRosenberg If you want to give me an example I will help. Don't forget you can set `x` in addition to using spaces, use justification, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `hjust=0` to left-justify the labels...

```
p <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = carat, y = price, color = cut)) +
  geom_point() 

p1 <- add_sub(p, label = "My Label", x = .125, hjust=0)
p2 <- add_sub(p1, label = "My Second Label", x = .125, hjust=0)

ggdraw(p2)
```

[image]

Comment: I'm so sorry - I think I meant I need the labels should be horizontally aligned, as in @Hack-R's answer

Comment: @JoshuaRosenberg No problem - I've learnt something new, so that's still worthwhile!