# Adding secondary x-axis label in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have produced this graph:

[image]

It is produced using this code:

```
ggplot(June, aes(x=Date, y=Count, fill=Species)) + 
  geom_bar(position='dodge', stat='identity') +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, vjust=0.5))
```

A sample of the data is here:

```
structure(list(Day = c("01/06/17", "01/06/17", "01/06/17", "01/06/17", 
"01/06/17", "01/06/17", "01/06/17", "01/06/17", "01/06/17", "01/06/17", 
"01/06/17", "01/06/17", "01/06/17", "01/06/17", "01/06/17", "01/06/17", 
"01/06/17", "01/06/17", "01/06/17", "01/06/17", "01/06/17", "01/06/17", 
"01/06/17", "01/06/17", "01/06/17", "01/06/17", "01/06/17", "01/06/17", 
"01/06/17", "01/06/17", "02/06/17", "02/06/17", "02/06/17", "02/06/17", 
"02/06/17", "02/06/17", "02/06/17", "02/06/17", "02/06/17", "02/06/17", 
"02/06/17", "02/06/17", "02/06/17", "02/06/17"), Time = c("20:00", 
"20:00", "20:00", "21:00", "21:00", "21:00", "22:00", "22:00", 
"22:00", "23:00", "23:00", "23:00", "00:00", "00:00", "00:00", 
"01:00", "01:00", "01:00", "02:00", "02:00", "02:00", "03:00", 
"03:00", "03:00", "04:00", "04:00", "04:00", "05:00", "05:00", 
"05:00", "20:00", "20:00", "20:00", "21:00", "21:00", "21:00", 
"22:00", "22:00", "22:00", "23:00", "23:00", "23:00", "00:00", 
"00:00"), Date = c("01/06/17 20:00", "01/06/17 20:00", "01/06/17 20:00", 
"01/06/17 21:00", "01/06/17 21:00", "01/06/17 21:00", "01/06/17 22:00", 
"01/06/17 22:00", "01/06/17 22:00", "01/06/17 23:00", "01/06/17 23:00", 
"01/06/17 23:00", "01/06/17 00:00", "01/06/17 00:00", "01/06/17 00:00", 
"01/06/17 01:00", "01/06/17 01:00", "01/06/17 01:00", "01/06/17 02:00", 
"01/06/17 02:00", "01/06/17 02:00", "01/06/17 03:00", "01/06/17 03:00", 
"01/06/17 03:00", "01/06/17 04:00", "01/06/17 04:00", "01/06/17 04:00", 
"01/06/17 05:00", "01/06/17 05:00", "01/06/17 05:00", "02/06/17 20:00", 
"02/06/17 20:00", "02/06/17 20:00", "02/06/17 21:00", "02/06/17 21:00", 
"02/06/17 21:00", "02/06/17 22:00", "02/06/17 22:00", "02/06/17 22:00", 
"02/06/17 23:00", "02/06/17 23:00", "02/06/17 23:00", "02/06/17 00:00", 
"02/06/17 00:00"), Species = c("Common Pipistrelle", "Soprano Pipistrelle", 
"Big bat sp.", "Common Pipistrelle", "Soprano Pipistrelle", "Big bat sp.", 
"Common Pipistrelle", "Soprano Pipistrelle", "Big bat sp.", "Common Pipistrelle", 
"Soprano Pipistrelle", "Big bat sp.", "Common Pipistrelle", "Soprano Pipistrelle", 
"Big bat sp.", "Common Pipistrelle", "Soprano Pipistrelle", "Big bat sp.", 
"Common Pipistrelle", "Soprano Pipistrelle", "Big bat sp.", "Common Pipistrelle", 
"Soprano Pipistrelle", "Big bat sp.", "Common Pipistrelle", "Soprano Pipistrelle", 
"Big bat sp.", "Common Pipistrelle", "Soprano Pipistrelle", "Big bat sp.", 
"Common Pipistrelle", "Soprano Pipistrelle", "Big bat sp.", "Common Pipistrelle", 
"Soprano Pipistrelle", "Big bat sp.", "Common Pipistrelle", "Soprano Pipistrelle", 
"Big bat sp.", "Common Pipistrelle", "Soprano Pipistrelle", "Big bat sp.", 
"Common Pipistrelle", "Soprano Pipistrelle"), Count = c(0L, 0L, 
0L, 20L, 0L, 0L, 85L, 0L, 1L, 9L, 0L, 0L, 7L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
22L, 0L, 0L, 38L, 0L, 0L, 162L, 2L, 0L, 146L, 5L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-44L), class = "data.frame")
```

What I would like to do would be to have the hours laid out as they are but with the date as a secondary over arching label which which goes from 00:00 to 23:00 like so:

[image]

Is it possible to do this in ggplot2?

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Please could you kindly replace the presentation of your data with the output of `dput(June)`?

Comment: Yes this is possible See this other post for concrete examples:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39717545/add-secondary-x-axis-labels-to-ggplot-with-one-x-axis

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add secondary X axis labels to ggplot with one X axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39717545/add-secondary-x-axis-labels-to-ggplot-with-one-x-axis)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract hours from `Date` column by `hours` function of `lubridate` package. Prelimenary datetime transformations could be done with this package as well. To put the  hours data in a desired order you can use `factor` function with customized `levels` argument. Please see the code below:

```
library(lubridate)    
library(ggplot2)

June <- structure(list(Day = c("01/06/17", "01/06/17", "01/06/17", "01/06/17", 
"01/06/17", "01/06/17", "01/06/17", "01/06/17", "01/06/17", "01/06/17", 
"01/06/17", "01/06/17", "01/06/17", "01/06/17", "01/06/17", "01/06/17", 
"01/06/17", "01/06/17", "01/06/17", "01/06/17", "01/06/17", "01/06/17", 
"01/06/17", "01/06/17", "01/06/17", "01/06/17", "01/06/17", "01/06/17", 
"01/06/17", "01/06/17", "02/06/17", "02/06/17", "02/06/17", "02/06/17", 
"02/06/17", "02/06/17", "02/06/17", "02/06/17", "02/06/17", "02/06/17", 
"02/06/17", "02/06/17", "02/06/17", "02/06/17"), Time = c("20:00", 
"20:00", "20:00", "21:00", "21:00", "21:00", "22:00", "22:00", 
"22:00", "23:00", "23:00", "23:00", "00:00", "00:00", "00:00", 
"01:00", "01:00", "01:00", "02:00", "02:00", "02:00", "03:00", 
"03:00", "03:00", "04:00", "04:00", "04:00", "05:00", "05:00", 
"05:00", "20:00", "20:00", "20:00", "21:00", "21:00", "21:00", 
"22:00", "22:00", "22:00", "23:00", "23:00", "23:00", "00:00", 
"00:00"), Date = c("01/06/17 20:00", "01/06/17 20:00", "01/06/17 20:00", 
"01/06/17 21:00", "01/06/17 21:00", "01/06/17 21:00", "01/06/17 22:00", 
"01/06/17 22:00", "01/06/17 22:00", "01/06/17 23:00", "01/06/17 23:00", 
"01/06/17 23:00", "01/06/17 00:00", "01/06/17 00:00", "01/06/17 00:00", 
"01/06/17 01:00", "01/06/17 01:00", "01/06/17 01:00", "01/06/17 02:00", 
"01/06/17 02:00", "01/06/17 02:00", "01/06/17 03:00", "01/06/17 03:00", 
"01/06/17 03:00", "01/06/17 04:00", "01/06/17 04:00", "01/06/17 04:00", 
"01/06/17 05:00", "01/06/17 05:00", "01/06/17 05:00", "02/06/17 20:00", 
"02/06/17 20:00", "02/06/17 20:00", "02/06/17 21:00", "02/06/17 21:00", 
"02/06/17 21:00", "02/06/17 22:00", "02/06/17 22:00", "02/06/17 22:00", 
"02/06/17 23:00", "02/06/17 23:00", "02/06/17 23:00", "02/06/17 00:00", 
"02/06/17 00:00"), Species = c("Common Pipistrelle", "Soprano Pipistrelle", 
"Big bat sp.", "Common Pipistrelle", "Soprano Pipistrelle", "Big bat sp.", 
"Common Pipistrelle", "Soprano Pipistrelle", "Big bat sp.", "Common Pipistrelle", 
"Soprano Pipistrelle", "Big bat sp.", "Common Pipistrelle", "Soprano Pipistrelle", 
"Big bat sp.", "Common Pipistrelle", "Soprano Pipistrelle", "Big bat sp.", 
"Common Pipistrelle", "Soprano Pipistrelle", "Big bat sp.", "Common Pipistrelle", 
"Soprano Pipistrelle", "Big bat sp.", "Common Pipistrelle", "Soprano Pipistrelle", 
"Big bat sp.", "Common Pipistrelle", "Soprano Pipistrelle", "Big bat sp.", 
"Common Pipistrelle", "Soprano Pipistrelle", "Big bat sp.", "Common Pipistrelle", 
"Soprano Pipistrelle", "Big bat sp.", "Common Pipistrelle", "Soprano Pipistrelle", 
"Big bat sp.", "Common Pipistrelle", "Soprano Pipistrelle", "Big bat sp.", 
"Common Pipistrelle", "Soprano Pipistrelle"), Count = c(0L, 0L, 
0L, 20L, 0L, 0L, 85L, 0L, 1L, 9L, 0L, 0L, 7L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
22L, 0L, 0L, 38L, 0L, 0L, 162L, 2L, 0L, 146L, 5L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-44L), class = "data.frame")

June$posix <- dmy_hm(June$Date)
June$Day_2 <- dmy(June$Day)
June$hour <- factor(hour(June$posix), levels = unique(hour(June$posix)))

ggplot(June, aes(x=hour, y=Count, fill=Species)) + 
  geom_bar(position='dodge', stat='identity') +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(vjust=0.5)) +
  xlab(paste0(range(June$Day_2), collapse = " - "))
```

Output:
[image: Species]