# Adding year below month in X-Axis of bar

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, x-axis

I would like to add year below the months in x-axis
I want it be same font but bigger and centered.
Something like this:

[image]

Comment: Please add some relevant code producing a plot with a date scale in the appropriate range of time.

Comment: There is no built in way to do this in ggplot2 analogous to how excel does it, for instance. You might look at using facets like in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36337286/6851825 or using text/annotations like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39718330/6851825

Comment: This is my code:  
onset_month_epigraph <- ggplot(onset_month_count, aes(fill=location_type, y=case_count, x=Month_Yr)) + 
  geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity") + 
  labs(y="Number of incidents", x="\
       Month of Start incident Period**", 
       title="Title") + 
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b-%y", date_breaks = "1 month")