# Can facets label be "merged" or combined?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

I have the following code in R using the ggplot2 package to create a stacked bar plot.

```
ggplot(example_data, aes(x = ID, y = amount, fill = Taxa)) +
 geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "fill") +
 facet_grid(.~City+Car+Color , scales = "free_x", space = "free_x") +
 labs(y = "Relative Adbundance")+
 theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),
       axis.ticks = element_blank(),
       axis.text.x = element_blank(),
       legend.position  = "none")
```

[image: Stacked barplot]

Is there a way to simply combine parts of different facets?  The picture below explains what I mean.  I want one gray bar saying "Milan" for all 5 facets that currently say Milan. I do not want to repeat the word "Milan" five times. Same for all the other circled groups.  Is this possible in ggplot2?  If not, does anyone know a work around?

[image: Circled stacked barplot]

Comment: please include some sample data. Otherwise I can't help. but you can try `facet_grid(City~Car+Color`

Comment: Have a look at this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/44628573/3926543).  A possible solution is to draw the first row and and second row seperately and combined it with the main plot with cowplot.

Comment: Don't think ggplot supports this. Hadley is very particular about letting people modify graphs. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13651627/nested-facet-plot-with-ggplot2).

Comment: Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40732543/seeking-workaround-for-gtable-add-grob-code-broken-by-ggplot-2-2-0) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39801041/ggplot2-have-common-facet-bar-in-outer-facet-panel-in-3-way-plot)?

Comment: @SandyMuspratt your suggestion in the first link worked great!  Thanks!

Comment: @SandyMuspratt I'm having an issue with the facet_grid scales and space.  I don't see how to add a picture here to show you the problem, but I will try to describe. Using code you have in the links above for my barplots I either have bars of the same width and the facets are jumbled a bit, or facets of the same size with bars of all different widths.  Is there a way to have a uniform bar width, and the facets adjust to fit them properly?

Comment: @nicole, I think I see the problem. Give me a couple of days.

Comment: @nicole, the problem was that I assumed that the panels have the same with. Have a look at the non-accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40732543/seeking-workaround-for-gtable-add-grob-code-broken-by-ggplot-2-2-0/40986592#40986592). Should work with panels of different widths.

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks!