# Add text outside plot area

Tags: r, ggplot2

Sample code

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, cyl, color = vs)) + geom_line()
```

How if it is possible to add arbitrary text to the x axis like in this example made using the plot above and then I wrote on it "arbitrary words"

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do so this may or may not generalise well.

That said, one possibility is to use `annotate` with `coord_cartesian(clip = "off")` to allow text outside the plot area.

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, cyl, color = vs)) +
    geom_line() +
    annotate("text", x = 12.5, y = 3.5, label = "Arbitrary text") +
    coord_cartesian(ylim = c(4, 8), clip = "off")
```

[image]

Comment: thanks so much this is really close but how can i line it up with x tick mark values 10 and 15 for example so it is in the middle or so?

Comment: Hi @bvowe; I think your only option is to manually tune the position through setting `x` and `y` inside `annotate`.

Answer (score 25):

You can use `tag` in `ggplot2` (see `?ggplot2::labs`) and specify it's position in `theme`

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, cyl, color = vs)) + 
    geom_line() +
    labs(tag = "arbitrary words") +
    theme(plot.tag.position = c(0.15, 0.02))
```

[image]

Comment: so nice, you saved my day

Comment: Is it possible to add multiple tags?