# Define color and radius of the background in shadowtext::element_shadowtext

Tags: r, ggplot2

Shadowtext allows to set the bg.color as well as the bg.r. However, I'm missing that option when using element_shadowtext. Is there a way to overcome that? I'm open to using other packages/ approaches.
Unfortunately ggtext does not allow to specify a textbox around axis labels.

```
data <- data.frame(ID= c("A", "B", "C"), Value =c(1.5,2,1.75))

library(ggplot2)
library(shadowtext)
ggplot(data, aes(x=ID, y=Value)) + 
  geom_col() + 
  theme(axis.text.x=shadowtext::element_shadowtext(color="white"),
        axis.title.x = element_blank())+
  shadowtext::geom_shadowtext(aes(label=Value), 
                              y=1, hjust=0.5,
                              bg.color="white", bg.r=0.2, color = "black")
```

[image]

Comment: Both functions use indeed different text grobs,  and the grob in element_shadowtext does indeed not have the same parameters. That might be worth a feature request... ;) Not sure if this will have big priority for the package maintainer though. An option would be to annotate your axis with geom_shadowtext instead.

Comment: many thanks! Seems like this is fairly stable even for polar plots...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst the solution by @Allan is very powerful, to me, the annotate-solution seems to be doing the job (thanks to @tjebo and [ggplot2 annotate on y-axis (outside of plot)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60592402/ggplot2-annotate-on-y-axis-outside-of-plot)):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(shadowtext)

ggplot(data, aes(x = ID, y = Value)) + 
  geom_col() +
  shadowtext::geom_shadowtext(aes(label=Value), 
                              y=1, hjust=0.5,
                              bg.color="white", bg.r=0.2, color = "black")+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(color=NA),
        axis.title.x = element_blank())+
  annotate("shadowText", x = c("A", "B", "C"), y = -0.15, label = c("A", "B", "C"), color="black", bg.color="grey", bg.r=0.2, fontface="bold")+
  coord_cartesian(clip="off",ylim = c(0,2))
```

[image]

and works even for polar plots, even though I don't know how to limit the y-axis while adding the labels, as `clip = 'off'` in `coord_polar` does not seem to allow the annotation outside of the scale.

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = ID, y = Value)) + 
  geom_col() +
  shadowtext::geom_shadowtext(aes(label=Value), 
                              y=1, hjust=0.5,
                              bg.color="white", bg.r=0.2, color = "black")+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.title.x = element_blank())+
  annotate("shadowText", x = c("A", "B", "C"), y = 2.1, label = c("A", "B", "C"), color="black", bg.color="grey", bg.r=0.2, fontface="bold")+
  coord_polar()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think one can achieve a nicer shadow effect using `with_shadow` from `ggfx`. Unforunately, it requires a bit more work to get the effect on axis elements. The radius is controlled by `sigma` and the color by the `colour` argument.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggfx)

p <- ggplot(data, aes(x = ID, y = Value)) + 
  geom_col() + 
  lapply(1:10, function(x) {
  with_shadow(colour = 'white', x_offset = 0, y_offset = 0, sigma = 3,
    geom_text(aes(label = Value), y = 1, hjust = 0.5)
  )}) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(color = 'white'),
        axis.title.x = element_blank())

p2 <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p))

p2$grobs[[7]]$children$axis$grobs[[2]]$children[[1]] <-
  do.call(grid::gList, lapply(1:10, function(x) {
  with_shadow(
    p2$grobs[[7]]$children$axis$grobs[[2]]$children[[1]],
    x_offset = 0, y_offset = 0, sigma = 5)
  }))

grid::grid.newpage()
grid::grid.draw(p2)
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks! The gaussian blur is less clear than just an outline (the plot later will be on a different background). I assume it should as well be possible to do the same using `shadowtext::shadowtextGrob()`
but only got that far 

`shadowtext::shadowtextGrob(
      p2$grobs[[7]]$children$axis$grobs[[2]]$children[[1]]$label,
      bg.colour="red")`

And what would I need to change for that approach to work as well for faceted and polar plots?