# ggplot geom_errorbar not on the bars?

Tags: r, ggplot2

My dataset looks like this:

```
df<-data.frame(Mean=c(56.0,63.8,46.9,48.5,39.8, 44.4, 51.9, 57.2, 40.5, 40.6),
              sd=c(24.0, 21.8, 24.4, 24.0, 21.0, 19.8, 22.4, 21.5, 20.5, 15.6),
              Quality=as.factor(c("P","M","P","M",
                                  "P","M", "P","M",
                                  "P","M")), 
              Category=c("A","B","C","D","E"),
              Insert= c(0.0, 0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 1.0))
```

Upon plotting, I get the following figure:
[image]

Basically, the error bars are not on the bars but are presented between the bars. Kindly let me know how can I correct the error bars so that they appear on the bars.

I use the following code:

```
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=Category, y=Mean, fill=Quality)) +
  geom_bar(position=position_dodge(), stat="identity",
           colour='black') + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Mean-sd, ymax=Mean+sd), width=.2)
print(p)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve your desired result you also have to dodge the error bars by using `position=position_dodge(.9)` where the .9 refers to the default width by which the bars get dodged:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x=Category, y=Mean, fill=Quality)) +
  geom_bar(position=position_dodge(), stat="identity",
           colour='black') + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Mean-sd, ymax=Mean+sd), width=.2, position=position_dodge(.9))
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer. Is it possible to change the order of the x-axis e.g., I want 'B' to come first then E, C, D, A? Also, bars for 'P' should come first followed by 'M'. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Sure. There are several options but a simple one would be to set the limits using `+ scale_x_discrete(limits = c("B", "E", "C", "D", "A"))`

Comment: Thanks Stefan. I just noticed that the values are not showing correctly in the bar chart. E.g., B's mean is 56.0 and 63.8 but in the plot it is below 50. Can you see why?

Comment: Hm. Have a look at your data and the plot. According to your example data the mean of B is 51.9 for Quality P (greenish bar) and 63.8 for Quality M (red bar) which corresponds to the values in the plot.

Comment: Thanks Stefan. There were some typos in the data. It's solved :)

Comment: You probably mean horizontal? Try `+ geom_hline(yintercept = c(25, 37.5))`

Comment: Hi Stefan, I have added 2 horizontal reference lines (1 at mean 20 and another at 40) in the bar plot using geom_hline but I can't label these reference lines in the plot. Could you help?

Comment: How do you want to label them? As a separate legend or do you want to add direct labels e.g. on top of the lines?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. On the top of the line or maybe on the yaxis.

Comment: To add the labels to the lines you could use `annotate`, e.g. `annotate(y = c(25, 37.5), label = paste("Mean:", c(25, 37.5)), hjust = -.05, vjust = -.2, x = -Inf, geom = "text")`. To add the labels on the y axis see e.g. my answer on [ggplot2 annotate on y-axis (outside of plot)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60592402/ggplot2-annotate-on-y-axis-outside-of-plot/60592639#60592639)