# ggplot2: add a multiplier on the top of axis label

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, axis

My numbers on the axis label were quite big, so I divided them by 10^n. Now, I would like to add a note on the top of axis label that the count is multiplied x 10^n. How to to that? Is it possible in ggplot? I can't use *geom_text* or similar, since the label is "out of the plot".

[image]

Comment: You can add `+ scale_y_continuous(labels = ~paste(.x, "* 10^5"))` to your plot

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60592402/ggplot2-annotate-on-y-axis-outside-of-plot

Comment: @AllanCameron it changes every single label tick, when I would like to contain the information just once, at the top of the label.

Comment: @BenBolker Tricky one! Nice, thank you! :)

Comment: If you think your post is a duplicate of that one, you can ask us to close it as a duplicate. If you think it would be worthwhile for future readers to see your solution using the info from the linked Q, you can go ahead and post your own answer (you may need to wait a little while before you're allowed to self-answer)

Comment: I investigated it a bit today, and there is a problem with the solution in linked Q: they use "labels" parameter that I already used to rescale my data. It seems to me that there should be any smooth solution of my problem but I don't see any for now. I would keep the post open for now, my question is in fact quite unique.