# How can I add an extra symbol in legend of a ggplot graph?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to add a symbol to the legend of the ggplot graph. Symbolic code of the ggplot is represented below, my question is, how can I draw that (*) symbol circled in the picture?

```
  library(ggplot2 )
ToothGrowth$dose <- as.factor(ToothGrowth$dose)
p <- ggplot(ToothGrowth, aes(x=dose, y=len, fill=dose)) + 
  geom_boxplot()
p
```

[image]

Comment: Tricky.  It would be easier to change the label of the dose-1 group to `1*` or `*1`. Would that be acceptable?  Otherwise, unless you want to do *very* deep graphics-hacking, I would try to export as PDF or SVG and hack it in Illustrator or Inkscape or ...

Comment: Starting in ggplot2_3.2.0, you can choose which glyph you want displayed in the legend keys using the `key_glyph` argument in the `geom_*()`.

See `?draw_key` for a list of the current glyphs available.

The `key_glyph` argument takes a key drawing function. You would have to write your own --- based on `draw_key_boxplot` --- to get what you want. 

I've never done that. As @BenBolker said, it's tricky.

Answer (score 5):

This takes some manual tweaking to get the positioning right, but you can add a symbol as an annotation outside of a plot using `annotate` and `coord_cartesian` with `clip = off`. Some hints taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54776363/12400385) answer.

```
ToothGrowth$dose <- as.factor(ToothGrowth$dose)

p <- ggplot(ToothGrowth, aes(x=dose, y=len, fill=dose)) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  annotate("point", x = 3.66, y = 18.5, shape = 8, size = 2) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(1, 3), clip = "off")

ggsave('test.jpg', p)
```

[image]

---

Edit: the shape in the above answer will be hidden by the legend if there is overlap. Using a `tag` is a similar solution but will allow the symbol to be plotted on top of the legend. It still takes some manual tweaking but the coordinates are positional to the figure not the data (which seems like a benefit).

```
ToothGrowth$dose <- as.factor(ToothGrowth$dose)

p <- ggplot(ToothGrowth, aes(x=dose, y=len, fill=dose)) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  labs(tag = '*') +
  theme(plot.tag.position = c(.94, 0.5),
        plot.tag = element_text(size = 30))

ggsave('test.jpg', p)
```

[image]

Comment: nice (if fragile)

Comment: As you mentioned in your comment, changing the label to `1 *` would be a more robust way to handle this.

Comment: not that I haven't done stuff like this, but I often end up being frustrated when something changes upstream and the hand-adjusted spacing then ends up being wrong ...