# How to fit custom long annotations geom_text inside plot area for a Donuts plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following stripped-down version of my real use-case where I create a donuts plot and would like to have those long labels fitting inside the whole plot but outside the donuts:

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(group = c("Cars", "Trucks", "Motorbikes"),n = c(25, 25, 50),
                 label2=c("Cars are blah blah blah", "Trucks some of the best in town", "Motorbikes are great if you ..."))

df$ymax = cumsum(df$n)
df$ymin = cumsum(df$n)-df$n
df$ypos = df$ymin+df$n/2
df$hjust = c(0,0,1)
df
#> df
#       group  n                          label2 ymax ymin ypos hjust
#1       Cars 25         Cars are blah blah blah   25    0 12.5     0
#2     Trucks 25 Trucks some of the best in town   50   25 37.5     0
#3 Motorbikes 50 Motorbikes are great if you ...  100   50 75.0     1

bp <- ggplot(df, aes(x="", y=n, fill=group)) + geom_rect(aes_string(ymax="ymax", ymin="ymin", xmax="2.5", xmin="2.0")) +
  theme(axis.title=element_blank(),axis.text=element_blank(),panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "grey50"),
  panel.grid=element_blank(),axis.ticks.length=unit(0,"cm"),axis.ticks.margin=unit(0,"cm"),
  legend.position="none",panel.spacing=unit(0,"lines"),plot.margin=unit(c(0,0,0,0),"lines"),complete=TRUE) + geom_text(ggplot2::aes_string(label="label2",x="2.6",y="ypos",hjust="hjust"))

pie <- bp + coord_polar("y", start=0) + scale_x_discrete(labels=df$label2)
pie
```

but no matter what I do this is what I get:

[image: Custom annotations overflow]

I have tried lowering the `xmax="2.5"` in an attempt to decrease the size of the Donuts plot and updating the x of the custom text accordingly e.g. +0.1 `x="2.6"`. However, this leads somehow to the whole plot re-scaling back to the same situation.

I have played with various plot sizes and margins but can't find the way ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you wish to shrink the donut relative to the entire plot area, so that there's more space to fit long annotations? I got the following to work based on the sample data. You may wish to tweak the parameters for your actual use case:

```
library(dplyr); library(stringr)

ggplot(df %>% 
          mutate(label2 = str_wrap(label2, width = 10)), #change width to adjust width of annotations
       aes(x="", y=n, fill=group)) + 
  geom_rect(aes_string(ymax="ymax", ymin="ymin", xmax="2.5", xmin="2.0")) +
  expand_limits(x = c(2, 4)) + #change x-axis range limits here
  # no change to theme
  theme(axis.title=element_blank(),axis.text=element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "grey50"),
        panel.grid=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.length=unit(0,"cm"),axis.ticks.margin=unit(0,"cm"),
        legend.position="none",panel.spacing=unit(0,"lines"),
        plot.margin=unit(c(0,0,0,0),"lines"),complete=TRUE) +
  geom_text(aes_string(label="label2",x="3",y="ypos",hjust="hjust")) +
  coord_polar("y", start=0) +
  scale_x_discrete()
```

[image: donut plot]

Comment: Thank you very much Z.Lin, are you aware of any way to crop the resulting extra space at the top and bottom of the plot?

Comment: @GiovanniAzua Nope, I don't think polar coordinates allows crop / zoom-in in the same way that cartesian coordinates do. However, as an alternative, you may wish to check the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12409960/ggplot2-annotate-outside-of-plot) on turning off the clipping so that the annotations can extend beyond plot area. (Note that you'll need to remove the grey outline for `panel.background` in `theme()`.)