# Is it possible to crop a plot when doing arrangeGrob?

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra

I have a use-case similar to the following where I create multiple plots and arrange them into some page layout using `gridExtra` to finally save it as a PDF with `ggsave`:

```
p1 <- generate_ggplot1(...)
p2 <- generate_ggplot2(...)

final <- gridExtra::arrangeGrob(p1, p2, ...)
ggplot2::ggsave(filename=output.file,plot=final, ...)
```

Is it possible to have plot `p2` cropped while arranging it into the page layout with `arrangeGrob`? The problem is that `p2` has a lot of extra space on the top and bottom of it that I'd like to get rid of and since `cropping` doesn't seem viable using `ggplot2` only I was thinking maybe is possible to crop it while arranging it ...

**UPDATE** Here is a self-contained example of my use-case, I'd like to get rid of the areas annotated red by whatever means:

```
library(ggplot2); library(dplyr); library(stringr); library(gridExtra)

df <- data.frame(group = c("Cars", "Trucks", "Motorbikes"),n = c(25, 25, 50),
                 label2=c("Cars are blah blah blah", "Trucks some of the best in town", "Motorbikes are great if you ..."))
df$ymax = cumsum(df$n)
df$ymin = cumsum(df$n)-df$n
df$ypos = df$ymin+df$n/2
df$hjust = c(0,0,1)

p1 <- ggplot(mtcars,aes(x=1:nrow(mtcars),y=mpg)) + geom_point()

p2 <- ggplot(df %>%
         mutate(label2 = str_wrap(label2, width = 10)), #change width to adjust width of annotations
       aes(x="", y=n, fill=group)) +
  geom_rect(aes_string(ymax="ymax", ymin="ymin", xmax="2.5", xmin="2.0")) +
  expand_limits(x = c(2, 4)) + #change x-axis range limits here
  # no change to theme
  theme(axis.title=element_blank(),axis.text=element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "grey50"),
        panel.grid=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.length=unit(0,"cm"),axis.ticks.margin=unit(0,"cm"),
        legend.position="none",panel.spacing=unit(0,"lines"),
        plot.margin=unit(c(0,0,0,0),"lines"),complete=TRUE) +
  geom_text(aes_string(label="label2",x="3",y="ypos",hjust="hjust")) +
  coord_polar("y", start=0) +
  scale_x_discrete()

final <- arrangeGrob(p1,p2,layout_matrix = rbind(c(1),c(2)),
                     widths=c(4),heights=c(4,4), padding=0.0,
                     respect=TRUE, clip="on")
plot(final)
```

And the output is:

[image: arrangeGrob output]

Comment: What about modifying the plot margins with `theme` prior to arranging with `arrangeGrob`?

Comment: I know but that's not enough, see the answer to this Q there is where the issue arises: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45817032/how-to-fit-custom-long-annotations-geom-text-inside-plot-area-for-a-donuts-plot I have tried everything I can think off to get rid of the vertical spaces but no luck so far.

Comment: I thought that maybe gridextra had some sort of negative margin to crop areas of a plot while placing it in the layout or for that matter manipulating the viewports for that purpose.

Comment: Can you provide data and code for two sample plots that we can work with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this, there's a multi-part solution needed.

First, for changing the margins in a single graph, using plot.margin inside theme() is a convenient way. However, this alone won't solve the issue if the goal is to combine multiple plots.

To do that you'll need a combination of plot.margin and a specific plotting order within arrangeGrob(). You'll need a specific order because plots get printed in the order you call them, and because of that, it will be easier to change the margins of plots that are layered behind other plots, instead of in front of plots. We can think of it like covering the plot margins we want to shrink by expanding the plot on top of the one we want to shrink. See the graphs below for illustration:

**Before plot.margin setting:**

[image]

```
#Main code for the 1st graph can be found in the original question.
```

**After plot.margin setting:**

[image]

```
#Main code for 2nd graph:
ggplot(df %>%
           mutate(label2 = str_wrap(label2, width = 10)),
                  aes(x="", y=n, fill=group)) +
  geom_rect(aes_string(ymax="ymax", ymin="ymin", xmax="2.5", xmin="2.0")) +
  geom_text(aes_string(label="label2",x="3",y="ypos",hjust="hjust")) +
  coord_polar(theta='y') +
  expand_limits(x = c(2, 4)) + 
  guides(fill=guide_legend(override.aes=list(colour=NA))) +
  theme(axis.line = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks=element_blank(),
        axis.title=element_blank(),
        axis.text.y=element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
        plot.margin = unit(c(-2, 0, -2, -.1), "cm"),
        legend.position = "none") +
 scale_x_discrete(limits=c(0, 1))
```

**After combining plot.margin setting and arrangeGrob() reordering:**

[image]

```
#Main code for 3rd graph:
p1 <- ggplot(mtcars,aes(x=1:nrow(mtcars),y=mpg)) + geom_point()

p2 <- ggplot(df %>%
               mutate(label2 = str_wrap(label2, width = 10)), #change width to adjust width of annotations
                      aes(x="", y=n, fill=group)) +
        geom_rect(aes_string(ymax="ymax", ymin="ymin", xmax="2.5", xmin="2.0")) +
        geom_text(aes_string(label="label2",x="3",y="ypos",hjust="hjust")) +
        coord_polar(theta='y') +
        expand_limits(x = c(2, 4)) + #change x-axis range limits here
        guides(fill=guide_legend(override.aes=list(colour=NA))) +
        theme(axis.line = element_blank(),
              axis.ticks=element_blank(),
              axis.title=element_blank(),
              axis.text.y=element_blank(),
              axis.text.x=element_blank(),
              panel.border = element_blank(),
              panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
              panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
              panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
              plot.margin = unit(c(-2, 0, -2, -.1), "cm"),
              legend.position = "none") +
        scale_x_discrete(limits=c(0, 1))

final <- arrangeGrob(p2,p1,layout_matrix = rbind(c(1),c(2)),
                     widths=c(4),heights=c(2.5,4),respect=TRUE)
```

Note that in the final code, I reversed the order you had in the arrangeGrob from p1,p2 to p2,p1. I then adjusted the height of the first object plotted, which is the one we want to shrink. This adjustment allows the earlier plot.margin adjustment to take effect, and as that takes effect, the graph printed last in order, which is P1, will start to take the space of what was the margins of P2. If you make one of these adjustments with out the others, the solution won't work. Each of these steps are important to produce the end result above.

Comment: I was afraid I was gonna have to get my hands dirty and fork `gridExtra` and family :D