# R, how to add one break to the default breaks in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels

Suppose I have the following issue: having a set of data, generate a chart indicating how many datapoints are below any given threshold.

This is fairly easy to achieve

```
n.data <- 215

set.seed(0)
dt <- rnorm(n.data) ** 2
x <- seq(0, 5, by=.2)
y <- sapply(x, function(i) length(which(dt < i)))

ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(x=x,y=y)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = n.data)
```

[image: Output]

The question is, suppose I want to add a label to indicate what the total number of observation was (`n.data`). How do I do that, while maintaining the other breaks as default?

The outcome I'd like looks something like the image below, generated with the code

```
ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(x=x,y=y)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = n.data) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(seq(0,200,50),n.data))
```

However, I'd like this to work even when I change the value of `n.data`, just by adding it to the default breaks.
(bonus points if you also get rid of the grid line between the last default break and the `n.data` one!)

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ggplot2 - annotate outside of plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12409960/ggplot2-annotate-outside-of-plot)

Comment: Did you manage to get this done? (Not a duplicate at all BTW)

Comment: @DanChaltiel, thanks for reopening this. I've added an answer about how I would approach this today.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Three years and some more knowledge of ggplot later, here's how I would do this today.

```
ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(x=x,y=y)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = n.data) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(pretty(y), n.data))
```

Comment: Thanks. Based on this I made it work for a more general case, where `n.data` is not necessarily the last value, via `sort(unique(c(my_values, pretty(y))))`

Comment: @PaulSchmidt I don't think you need to do this? Worked fine for me without sorting, but I also didn't have duplicate values.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can get rid of the grid line between the last auto break and the manual one :

```
theme_update(panel.grid.minor=element_blank())
```

For the rest, I can't quite understand your question, as when you change `n.data`, your break is updated.