# ggplot: add manually labelled tick marks on top of automatic tick marks

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to highlight the point with the lowest y value by attempting the following:
1) draw a line from this point down to the x-axis and another to the y-axis; and
2) add a manual tick mark with this point's x and y value on the x-axis and y-axis, respectively. This manual tick mark must be added in addition to the automatic tick marks on both axes.

Sample data:

```
df <- data.frame(x=1:100,y=rnorm(100,10,1))
ggplot(df) +
  geom_point(aes(x=x,y=y))
```

Edit:

Here's an illustration of what I am attempting:

[image]

Comment: Have a look at http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/annotate.html to get some inspiration and also http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Lines_(ggplot2)/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unclear exactly what you want this to look like but you could do one of two options. You could either use `geom_vline()` or `geom_segment()`. Vline will do a line from the bottom to the top, but it sounds like you may prefer to use segment. Try this:

```
+ geom_segment(x = min(x), xend = min(x), y = 0, yend = 1)
```

If you change the `yend` argument you could make the tick smaller or larger. Drawing one for the max value should be as simple as swapping the `min()` arguments for `max()` arguments. Or you could just input the values manually. Alternatively, you could add a vline to go the full height of the panel with:

```
+ geom_vline(xintercept = min(x))
```

You can read more about both [here](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-add-straight-lines-to-a-plot-horizontal-vertical-and-regression-lines). If this doesn't help much, you can provide a proper [reprex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and maybe a sketch of your desired output we can modify that code to get a bit closer to what you want.

## edit:

Writing outside of the plot window is a bit more difficult, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12409960/ggplot2-annotate-outside-of-plot) link may help you. I've tried it on a few and always found that in my cases it was easier to use a different solution. Here's one option:

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(123)  # so we have the same toy data

df <- data.frame(x=1:100,y=rnorm(100,10,1))

ggplot(df) +
  geom_point(aes(x=x,y=y)) +
  geom_segment(x=0, xend=18, y=8.033383, yend=8.033383) +  # draw to x axis
  geom_segment(x=18, xend=18, y=0, yend=8.033383) +  # draw to y axis
  annotate("text", 18.2, 8.2, label="(8, 8.03)", size=3)  # ordered pair just above it
```

If you didn't want to draw all the way to the point you could just change the first `xend` and `yend` arguments where the `x`/`y` start at zero to be come just above the edge of the plot window.

Comment: see the edited post: I have added an illustration. Thank you for the geom_segment code. Do you know how to add the manual tick marks on top of the automatically generated ones?

Comment: See my edit. I'm not as familiar with writing outside the plot window but I gave you a link that may help and a workaround.

Comment: Thank you, seeellayewhy!