# R: Workaround to add a 2nd x-axis (just need the Information)

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph

I am trying to reproduce a graph with ggplot2. However, I am stucking at the point to add 2nd x-axis (or some Workaround to set the Information above the graph, that Looks like a 2nd x-axis):

[image]

Some ideas how I can replicate the above x-axis (the values from 8 to 1) with ggplot2 ? Since items like sec.axis are only can transform the "main x-axis". But I need to specify a new variable to this axis.

dput of my data:

```
structure(list(df = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 8L), lambda = c(1.07439006452315, 0.981356323478726, 
0.888322582434298, 0.79528884138987, 0.702255100345442, 0.609221359301013, 
0.516187618256585, 0.423153877212157, 0.330120136167729, 0.237086395123301, 
0.144052654078873, 0.0510189130344448, -0.0420148280099833, -0.135048569054412, 
-0.22808231009884, -0.321116051143268, -0.414149792187696, -0.507183533232124, 
-0.600217274276552, -0.69325101532098, -0.786284756365408, -0.879318497409836, 
-0.972352238454264, -1.06538597949869, -1.15841972054312, -1.25145346158755, 
-1.34448720263198, -1.4375209436764, -1.53055468472083, -1.62358842576526, 
-1.71662216680969, -1.80965590785412, -1.90268964889855, -1.99572338994297, 
-2.0887571309874, -2.18179087203183, -2.27482461307626, -2.36785835412069, 
-2.46089209516511, -2.55392583620954, -2.64695957725397, -2.7399933182984, 
-2.83302705934283, -2.92606080038725, -3.01909454143168, -3.11212828247611, 
-3.20516202352054, -3.29819576456497, -3.3912295056094, -3.48426324665382, 
-3.57729698769825, -3.67033072874268, -3.76336446978711, -3.85639821083154, 
-3.94943195187596, -4.04246569292039, -4.13549943396482, -4.22853317500925, 
-4.32156691605368, -4.4146006570981, -4.50763439814253), cv = c(19.3204817596425, 
19.1213671183882, 18.8773619995934, 18.6774892277955, 18.4835208555261, 
18.2897100568571, 18.0708770943675, 17.8323381067138, 17.6066859085164, 
17.4107724812813, 17.2471326487745, 17.1112451165908, 16.997104959334, 
16.8967562285072, 16.8077689802323, 16.7318984219901, 16.664519563401, 
16.6099449837552, 16.5672421336285, 16.5338375435914, 16.5069624936659, 
16.4847328120999, 16.4657265866304, 16.448486821364, 16.4320103091219, 
16.4170983362393, 16.4064896391581, 16.4015230468903, 16.3998890848963, 
16.4005528671873, 16.4019304286688, 16.4036216529537, 16.4067528891749, 
16.4100161601128, 16.4132605899296, 16.4165395864851, 16.4199042281655, 
16.4233781838506, 16.426769853484, 16.4296843196208, 16.4324964410732, 
16.4350449454725, 16.4374759407496, 16.4398124053385, 16.4420255031771, 
16.4441043985724, 16.4460493459917, 16.4478923998711, 16.4496464721569, 
16.4512671846374, 16.452755372096, 16.4541355260057, 16.4554098004139, 
16.4565844426538, 16.4576660291829, 16.4586609088677, 16.4595751922309, 
16.4604147172934, 16.4611850278838, 16.4618913616671, 16.4625380587224
), cvup = c(101.889140389973, 100.915687017117, 99.5338387199812, 
98.3978656187505, 97.3342038792051, 96.2945440744101, 95.0979526365153, 
93.8258765150077, 92.6520846572708, 91.6517399890698, 90.8248921229177, 
90.1446520206297, 89.5760195678867, 89.0768732000128, 88.6326431812006, 
88.2580379443768, 87.9285651379465, 87.6667164658585, 87.46798180289, 
87.3169642537599, 87.1985439655234, 87.1045127640699, 87.0287736938534, 
86.9594484427788, 86.8898849898434, 86.8259652241002, 86.7845239044576, 
86.774810006682, 86.7837821754338, 86.8070951335521, 86.8328275771822, 
86.8596790387766, 86.8928184061523, 86.9251464730962, 86.9562034124854, 
86.9862365456731, 87.0154823680639, 87.0440872246828, 87.0713299919281, 
87.0954330102414, 87.1183027814994, 87.1395653522666, 87.1596335907399, 
87.1785452291483, 87.1962104973293, 87.2126312068382, 87.227857678753, 
87.242092892569, 87.2554416547414, 87.2677222300107, 87.2789778575492, 
87.289357594465, 87.2989009052576, 87.3076669365146, 87.3157130025923, 
87.3230930779294, 87.3298580386636, 87.3360556493216, 87.3417305999759, 
87.3469245807757, 87.3516741645461), cvund = c(91.3156772064514, 
90.2979841667648, 89.239781275953, 88.3770266592041, 87.5010046760554, 
86.6025564941611, 85.6108183071601, 84.4975045521302, 83.4147744278928, 
82.4559848237428, 81.6464343648275, 80.9677991452778, 80.3950300254529, 
79.8906890850589, 79.4450466211225, 79.0609462755239, 78.7166304960634, 
78.4327333716939, 78.2044395333952, 78.0214111821543, 77.8710809711359, 
77.7428153569291, 77.6284921724508, 77.525419770861, 77.4302181013752, 
77.3450181382926, 77.2803724871237, 77.2404204622206, 77.215108673529, 
77.1984335383206, 77.1864767095062, 77.1765374907606, 77.1747104855969, 
77.1750151280321, 77.1764024868109, 77.1791593191782, 77.1835599135915, 
77.1896946138232, 77.196368542912, 77.2014101859665, 77.2066616292326, 
77.2108841024579, 77.2151258167557, 77.2195788242368, 77.2240445344412, 
77.2284127788855, 77.2326357811641, 77.2368311061419, 77.2410230668273, 
77.2449496163633, 77.2485758634109, 77.251997665592, 77.255197098881, 
77.2581774900237, 77.2609472892365, 77.2635160107474, 77.265893883645, 
77.2680915236126, 77.2701196788622, 77.2719890358956, 77.2737064226781
)), row.names = c("s0", "s1", "s2", "s3", "s4", "s5", "s6", "s7", 
"s8", "s9", "s10", "s11", "s12", "s13", "s14", "s15", "s16", 
"s17", "s18", "s19", "s20", "s21", "s22", "s23", "s24", "s25", 
"s26", "s27", "s28", "s29", "s30", "s31", "s32", "s33", "s34", 
"s35", "s36", "s37", "s38", "s39", "s40", "s41", "s42", "s43", 
"s44", "s45", "s46", "s47", "s48", "s49", "s50", "s51", "s52", 
"s53", "s54", "s55", "s56", "s57", "s58", "s59", "s60"), class = "data.frame")
```

the short Version of my Code (abstracted by axis names and more):

```
 p <- ggplot(data=data_cv, aes(x=lambda, y=cv)) + geom_point(colour = "blue") 
p2 <- p + geom_errorbar(data=data_cv, mapping=aes(ymin=cvund, ymax=cvup), width=0.2, size=0.1, color="black")
```

Comment: dput your data please?

Comment: As you've found, you can only supply transformations with `sec.axis`. ggplot is [deliberately](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3101876/4497050) built so you can't make dual axes that aren't just conversions.

Comment: Edited: the column "df" contains the numbers that I am trying to plot above. It doesnt have to be an axis. A nice work around would also be to plot the Information above the plot

Comment: @alistaire would there be a work around to just add the Information above the plot that it would look like a 2nd axis ?

Comment: If you [go into grid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12417481/4497050), most anything is possible (albeit sometimes with significant work and frustration). If you're reaching that point, it's usually a sign that you should rethink your plot, though.

Comment: Any reason you absolutely need to do this in ggplot? The example looks like something produced by the glmnet package [here](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/glmnet/glmnet_alpha.html). I'm curious whether this is an assignment of some kind, since I just saw another [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50986045/r-ggplot2-adding-a-2nd-x-axis-above-the-plott-with-new-values-no-transformatio) posted 10 hours before this one.

Answer (score 1):

You can create the extra axis as a separate plot, then grid arrange it together with the main plot:

```
library(cowplot)
data_cv=data.frame(x = seq(-5,5,0.1), y = exp(seq(-5,5,0.1)))

p1 = ggplot(data_cv, aes(x,y)) + geom_line()
p2 = ggplot(data_cv, aes(x,y)) + geom_blank() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(-5,5,length.out = 10),
                     labels = c(8,8,8,8,8,7,6,5,4,3)) +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(color = NA),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_text(color = NA),
        axis.ticks.y = element_line(color = NA),
        axis.line.y = element_line(color = NA))

plot_grid(p2,p1,align = 'h', ncol = 1, rel_heights = c(1,5))
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to connect the axis, so it would look like one plot ?