# How to write a list of words in the second y-axis with ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Let's assume I have the following dataframe:

```
df = data.frame(Date = seq(as.Date("2001-01-01"), as.Date("2020-12-31"), by = "day"),
          Data = randn(length(seq(as.Date("2001-01-01"), as.Date("2020-12-31"), by = "day")),1),
          stringsAsFactors = F)
```

and a vector of words:

```
key_words = c("ciao", "bye", "thanks", "for", "your", "help", "SO", "is", "amazing", "really")
```

I would like to plot it with ggplot by adding, in the second y-axis the vector of words `key_words`, similarly to the figure below:

[image]

This is the simple code to plot the graph in ggplot:

```
ggplot(df) + geom_line(aes(x = Date, y = Data), col = "blue") + labs(y = "", x = "") + theme_classic()
```

Is there anyone who can help me add `key_words` as a column in the figure above?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65744248/how-to-add-a-free-text-entry-as-a-legend-to-ggplot is what your are looking for?

Comment: @stefan thanks a lot! I typed anything but that title :D thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you want to link the key words place with the fist y axis, try this :

```
ggplot(df) + geom_line(aes(x = Date, y = Data), col = "blue") + labs(y = "", x = "") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(-4, 5), breaks = -5:5,
                      , sec.axis = sec_axis( ~.  , breaks = -4:5,  labels = key_words, 
                                             name = "name of the new axis")
                     )
                     +
  theme_classic()
```