# r dot plot with sample size

Tags: r, ggplot2

My goal is to recreate a dot plot like this using ggplot

[image]

So far this is what I have done.

```
# Load dataset
library(rms)
getHdata(titanic3)

# Ensure the variables in right format

titanic3$sibsp <- as.factor(as.character(titanic3$sibsp))
titanic3$parch <- as.factor(as.character(titanic3$parch))


titanic3 %>%
    select(c(sex,pclass, survived, sibsp, parch )) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -c(survived)) %>% group_by(name, value) %>%
  summarise(survived = mean(survived, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = value, y = survived, fill = factor(value))) + 
  geom_point() + coord_flip() +
  facet_wrap(~name, scales = "free_y", nrow = 4, strip.position = "top") +
  theme(panel.spacing = unit(0, "lines"),
        panel.border = element_rect(fill = NA),
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "none",
        strip.placement = "outside")
```

The issue is

1. In my plot the levels within each variable is reversed. Highest responses levels are on the top and lowest response levels are at the bottom. For example, plcass is displayed as 3,2,1. I like this to be reversed , to show 1,2,3 , lowest level first , so on.
2. I dont know how to add N at each levels, similar to the expected plot above.

I not a fan of dotplot because it is difficult to change the size of points, x axis labels etc. So any help resolving these issues is much appreciated. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I added `n=n()` in the `summarise()`
2. I remove the superseded `coord_flip()`, I swapped the `aes()` instead.
3. I reversed the factor with `mutate(value2 =factor(value, ordered = TRUE) %>% fct_rev() )`. `ungroup()` is required beforehand.
4. For the annotation on the right, [thanks to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51312611/13203906).

The code:

```
library(rms)
library(tidyverse)
Hmisc::getHdata(titanic3)

# Ensure the variables in right format
titanic3$sibsp <- as.factor(as.character(titanic3$sibsp))
titanic3$parch <- as.factor(as.character(titanic3$parch))


titanic3 %>%
  select(c(sex, pclass, survived, sibsp, parch)) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -c(survived)) %>%
  group_by(name, value) %>%
  summarise(survived = mean(survived, na.rm = TRUE), n = n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(value2 = factor(value, ordered = TRUE) %>% fct_rev()) %>%
  ggplot(aes(y = value2, x = survived, fill = factor(value))) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~name, scales = "free_y", nrow = 4, strip.position = "top") +
  theme(
    panel.spacing = unit(0, "lines"),
    panel.border = element_rect(fill = NA),
    axis.title.y = element_blank(),
    legend.position = "none",
    strip.placement = "outside"
  ) +
  geom_text(aes(x = 0.82, label = paste0("n = ", as.character(n)), y = value2), hjust = 0) +
  coord_cartesian(
    xlim = c(0, 0.75), # This focuses the x-axis on the range of interest
    clip = "off"
  ) +
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(1, 5, 1, 1), "lines"))
```

[image: Plot with number of observation on the right]

Comment: how do i move the  sample size n= on the right margins bit more inside, to the left ?

Comment: I fixed the  `geom_text()` position  at `x=0.82 ` , you can adjust as you want. You might adjust `xlim()` as well , and the margin in `theme(plot.margin=[...])`

Answer (score 0):

You can change the default order of values by making the variable a factor and ordering it:

```
titanic3$pclass <- ordered(titanic3$pclass, levels = c(3,2,1))
```

I don't know how to help you with the column of sums though.