# How can I add a border along only one side of a ggplot2 plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to know how to add a border to my plot on only one side. I have this plot:

```r
library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(title = "Title",
       subtitle = "Subtitle")

p
```

[image: plain plot]

<sup>Created on 2019-12-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

I would like to add a horizontal line above the title, like this:

[image]

I cannot figure out how to do this. I have tried `theme(plot.background = element_rect())`, but this adds a border on all sides of the plot.

In this case I would prefer not to use gridExtra:grid.arrange() or {patchwork} to add a line grob above the plot.

Comment: just in case this gridExtra is different to what you were not wanting: `
`grid.arrange(p,   top=linesGrob(x=0:1,y=0.5, gp=gpar(col="blue", lwd=10)),              padding=unit(1, "lines"))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is based on answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10525957/how-to-draw-lines-outside-of-plot-area-in-ggplot2).

Note that the `title = "Title"` was changed to have a blank line of title text above what is printed. It is now `title = "\nTitle"`.

It uses package `grid`, functions `linesGrob` and `grid.draw`.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)

p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(title = "\nTitle",
       subtitle = "Subtitle")

p1 <- p + annotation_custom(grob = linesGrob(y = unit(3, "lines"), 
                                             gp = gpar(col = "blue")), 
                            xmin = -Inf, xmax = Inf, ymin = Inf, ymax = Inf)

gt <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p1))
gt$layout$clip[gt$layout$name=="panel"] <- "off"
grid.draw(gt)
```

[image]

To extend the line to the margins along the x axis, also set a value of `x` in `linesGrob`. The right side value is a large integer number because apparently `linesGrob` doesn't accept `Inf`.

```
p2 <- p + annotation_custom(grob = linesGrob(x = unit(c(-2, 100), "lines"),
                                             y = unit(3, "lines"), 
                                             gp = gpar(col = "blue")), 
                            xmin = -Inf, xmax = Inf, ymin = Inf, ymax = Inf)

gt <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p2))
gt$layout$clip[gt$layout$name=="panel"] <- "off"
grid.draw(gt)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Before I accept the answer: do you know how to extend the line to the boundary of the plot, rather than the panel?

Comment: @MattCowgill No, I don't. But I believe that the method used in the answer in the link shows how to draw something in any side of the panel. To *extend* a line drawn on one side might be a different problem, though.

Comment: @MattCowgill Try `linesGrob(x = unit(c(-2, 100), "lines"), etc)`.