# ggplot2 custom grob will not extend outside of plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, grob

I am trying to use `annotate_custom` to create lines outside of my plot to divide my axis into sections. I am aware of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10525957/how-to-draw-lines-outside-of-plot-area-in-ggplot2) that asks a similar question, but for some reason, using a negative value as the min value for the line does not extend the lines outside of the plot.

Sample code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)

data("iris")
ggplot(iris, aes(x=Species, y=Petal.Width)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity')+coord_flip()+
  annotation_custom(grob = linesGrob(), xmin = 2.5, xmax = 2.5, ymin = -90, ymax = 0)+
  annotation_custom(grob = linesGrob(), xmin = 1.5, xmax = 1.5, ymin = -90, ymax = 0)
```

What I get:
[image]

What I want:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be default, the setting is to not allow any graphical elements to clip outside the plot area.  You can turn off clipping via any of the `coord_*` functions (ex. `coord_cartesian()`, `coord_fixed()`...), so in your case, use `coord_flip(clip="off")` to allow grobs to extend anywhere in your plot:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x=Species, y=Petal.Width)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity')+coord_flip(clip='off')+
  annotation_custom(grob = linesGrob(), xmin = 2.5, xmax = 2.5, ymin = -90, ymax = 0)+
  annotation_custom(grob = linesGrob(), xmin = 1.5, xmax = 1.5, ymin = -90, ymax = 0)
```

[image]