Add borders to x-axis labels by their categories
I want to add borders to x-axis labels, the labels are divided into three categories, the color of the label are set by their category. I want to add borders for each categories instead of every labels. I tried geom_label() but it can only add borders for every labels. Also I want to add titles for each categories like the sample picture. Thanks.
# set color
ontology_colors <- c("BP" = "#339970",   # red
                     "CC" = "#ff6633",   # green
                     "MF" = "#9999ff")   # blue
# start to draw
plot<- ggplot(data = eGO_top10, aes(x = Description, y = enrichment_score, fill = ONTOLOGY)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(width = 0.2)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = sprintf("%.2f", enrichment_score)), 
            position = position_dodge(width = 0.4), vjust = -0.3,size = 2) +
# add labels for x-axis
  geom_text(data = eGO_top10, aes(x = Description, y = 0, label = Description, color =ONTOLOGY),  
           angle = 75, hjust = "top", vjust = 1, size = 3,stat = "identity",position = position_nudge(x=0.1,y=-0.5),show.legend = FALSE)+
  coord_cartesian(clip="off")+
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0))+
  scale_color_manual(values = ontology_colors)+
  scale_fill_manual(values = ontology_colors) + 
  facet_grid(~ ONTOLOGY,scales = "free_x", space = "fixed", margins = FALSE) + 
  guides(fill = guide_legend(title = "ONTOLOGY", override.aes = list(color = NULL)))+
  labs(x = "", y = "Enrichment Score", fill = "ONTOLOGY",title = "") + 
  theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = "white"), 
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),  
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
        strip.text = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
        panel.border = element_rect(fill = NA, colour = "white"),
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        panel.spacing = unit(0,"cm"),
        plot.margin = margin(1,0,9,1,"cm"),
        axis.line = element_line(color = "black"))  
ggsave("GO_barplot_Enrichment_Score.tiff", plot, width = 5444, height = 4612, units = "px", dpi = 600)


This is the plot I get:

This is the result I want to achieve:

DATA like this
structure(list(ONTOLOGY = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), levels = c("BP", "CC", "MF"), class = "factor"), 
    ID = c("GO:0070141", "GO:0010749", "GO:1900543", "GO:1903596", 
    "GO:0010885", "GO:0001660", "GO:0045980", "GO:0071492", "GO:0072584", 
    "GO:0010745", "GO:0042627", "GO:0034361", "GO:0034385", "GO:0097136", 
    "GO:0071682", "GO:0031143", "GO:0060198", "GO:0044292", "GO:0099523", 
    "GO:0099524", "GO:0004707", "GO:0008035", "GO:0004708", "GO:0071813", 
    "GO:0071814", "GO:0070513", "GO:0030169", "GO:0034185", "GO:0034452", 
    "GO:0097153"), Description = c("response to UV-A", "regulation of nitric oxide mediated signal transduction", 
    "negative regulation of purine nucleotide metabolic process", 
    "regulation of gap junction assembly", "regulation of cholesterol storage", 
    "fever generation", "negative regulation of nucleotide metabolic process", 
    "cellular response to UV-A", "caveolin-mediated endocytosis", 
    "negative regulation of macrophage derived foam cell differentiation", 
    "chylomicron", "very-low-density lipoprotein particle", "triglyceride-rich plasma lipoprotein particle", 
    "Bcl-2 family protein complex", "endocytic vesicle lumen", 
    "pseudopodium", "clathrin-sculpted vesicle", "dendrite terminus", 
    "presynaptic cytosol", "postsynaptic cytosol", "MAP kinase activity", 
    "high-density lipoprotein particle binding", "MAP kinase kinase activity", 
    "lipoprotein particle binding", "protein-lipid complex binding", 
    "death domain binding", "low-density lipoprotein particle binding", 
    "apolipoprotein binding", "dynactin binding", "cysteine-type endopeptidase activity involved in apoptotic process"
    ), GeneRatio = c("6/130", "5/130", "4/130", "4/130", "7/130", 
    "4/130", "4/130", "4/130", "4/130", "5/130", "3/128", "4/128", 
    "4/128", "2/128", "4/128", "3/128", "2/128", "2/128", "2/128", 
    "2/128", "4/126", "3/126", "4/126", "6/126", "6/126", "2/126", 
    "3/126", "3/126", "2/126", "2/126"), BgRatio = c("14/18870", 
    "12/18870", "10/18870", "10/18870", "19/18870", "11/18870", 
    "11/18870", "11/18870", "11/18870", "14/18870", "12/19886", 
    "20/19886", "20/19886", "10/19886", "23/19886", "18/19886", 
    "12/19886", "13/19886", "13/19886", "13/19886", "16/18496", 
    "13/18496", "18/18496", "31/18496", "31/18496", "11/18496", 
    "17/18496", "17/18496", "12/18496", "12/18496"), pvalue = c(2.73e-10, 
    1.09e-08, 4.37e-07, 4.37e-07, 2.94e-11, 6.84e-07, 6.84e-07, 
    6.84e-07, 6.84e-07, 2.74e-08, 5.49e-05, 7.33e-06, 7.33e-06, 
    0.001788423, 1.32e-05, 0.000198047, 0.002600997, 0.003060985, 
    0.003060985, 0.003060985, 3.51e-06, 8.4e-05, 5.83e-06, 5.68e-08, 
    5.68e-08, 0.002432413, 0.000195749, 0.000195749, 0.002905909, 
    0.002905909), p.adjust = c(7.09e-09, 1.65e-07, 4.09e-06, 
    4.09e-06, 1.02e-09, 6.23e-06, 6.23e-06, 6.23e-06, 6.23e-06, 
    3.81e-07, 0.000666958, 0.000124528, 0.000124528, 0.010605762, 
    0.0002102, 0.001683402, 0.013265087, 0.014454649, 0.014454649, 
    0.014454649, 0.000128395, 0.001322806, 0.000165588, 4.09e-06, 
    4.09e-06, 0.017026888, 0.002740491, 0.002740491, 0.018776645, 
    0.018776645), qvalue = c(3.25e-09, 7.55e-08, 1.88e-06, 1.88e-06, 
    4.67e-10, 2.86e-06, 2.86e-06, 2.86e-06, 2.86e-06, 1.75e-07, 
    0.000426743, 7.97e-05, 7.97e-05, 0.006785936, 0.000134493, 
    0.001077099, 0.008487465, 0.009248589, 0.009248589, 0.009248589, 
    8.9e-05, 0.000917234, 0.000114819, 2.83e-06, 2.83e-06, 0.011806447, 
    0.001900257, 0.001900257, 0.013019729, 0.013019729), geneID = c("MME/EGFR/AKT1/MMP3/MMP1/TIMP1", 
    "VEGFA/INS/EGFR/CBS/PDE5A", "TP53/H19/PARP1/TSPO", "ACE/IL1B/AGT/CAV1", 
    "APOB/LPL/PPARG/CD36/SCARB1/NR1H3/NR1H2", "TNF/IL1B/IL1A/PTGS2", 
    "TP53/H19/PARP1/TSPO", "MME/MMP3/MMP1/TIMP1", "MAPK1/SRC/CAV1/MAPK3", 
    "CRP/PPARG/ADIPOQ/NR1H3/NR1H2", "APOB/LPL/APOC3", "APOB/APOA1/LPL/APOC3", 
    "APOB/APOA1/LPL/APOC3", "BCL2/BAX", "MPO/APOB/APOA1/HSP90AA1", 
    "MAPK1/MAPK3/RAF1", "GAD1/GAD2", "SRC/HSP90AA1", "HTT/CALB1", 
    "HTT/CALB1", "MAPK1/MAPK14/MAPK3/MAPK10", "APOA1/CD36/SCARB1", 
    "MAPK1/MAPK14/MAPK3/MAPK10", "MAPT/CRP/APOA1/LPL/CD36/SCARB1", 
    "MAPT/CRP/APOA1/LPL/CD36/SCARB1", "BCL2/BAX", "CRP/CD36/SCARB1", 
    "MAPT/LPL/SCARB1", "MAPT/HTT", "CASP3/CASP9"), Count = c(6L, 
    5L, 4L, 4L, 7L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L), 
    enrichment_score = c(62.21, 60.48, 58.06, 58.06, 53.48, 52.78, 
    52.78, 52.78, 52.78, 51.84, 38.84, 31.07, 31.07, 31.07, 27.02, 
    25.89, 25.89, 23.9, 23.9, 23.9, 36.7, 33.88, 32.62, 28.41, 
    28.41, 26.69, 25.9, 25.9, 24.47, 24.47)), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -30L), groups = structure(list(
    ONTOLOGY = structure(1:3, levels = c("BP", "CC", "MF"), class = "factor"), 
    .rows = structure(list(1:10, 11:20, 21:30), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -3L), .drop = TRUE))


this might be helpfull: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10525957/how-to-draw-lines-outside-of-plot-area-in-ggplot2
